# Additional Badge Ideas

Tags: discussion, badges, easter-eggs

As the title suggests does anyone have ideas for additional badges for SO?

I liked the idea of 'hidden' ones that are triggered by odd, random criteria. Basically Easter eggs.

Also:

- Member of all 3 stack overflow sites

Edit: Made it a community wiki so people can edit easier.

Comment: I wonder if we could get Jeff to comment on the status of badge requests.

Comment: Locking ... I can not find anything here .. its ridiculous. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58700/is-badge-request-obsolete/58701#58701 If you have real badge suggestions please post them separately as feature requests. If you have less serious ones post them when its Friday in Iceland.

Answer (score 199):

*Based on suggestions in the comments from Jonik, Bill the Lizard, and Chris Lutz, I've updated the badge name and other details...*

**Sportsmanship**: Awarded when you've given 100 upvotes to non-wiki competing answers (i.e. other user's answers to questions that you have also answered and earned at least one upvote for). This could be awarded multiple times, once for each successive set of 100 upvotes you give.

**NOTE:** Hurray! [This has now been implemented][1], although it can only be earned once.

Comment: now this is a good one

Comment: Only non-CW stuff should probably be counted for this (it's common to post an answer and still upvote lots of other ones in CW polls)

Comment: Not sure about the name though (http://www.chacha.com/question/what-is-a-self&%2345%3B-defeatist). How about "Selfless", "Constructive", "Supportive", "Principled"... Hmm, or even "Fair Play", "Sportsmanship" :) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sportsmanship If negative badges were given, "Sore Loser" would be a nice one for some (opposite) situations.

Comment: @Jonik: Good point about only counting non-CW upvotes. I was actually thinking the same thing but forgot to say it explicitly.

Comment: I like "Principled" and "Sportsmanship" or "Sportsmanlike".  I also like "Evenhanded" or "Scrupulous".

Comment: "Sportsmanship", definitely

Comment: This is definitely the best idea yet.

Comment: Can we please not have "man" in the name of the badge.  "Sporting" would get the point across without the sexism.

Comment: @Richard: Well, that's the first time I've ever heard the word "Sportsmanship" referred to as sexist. Honestly, the political-correctness-has-gone-to-far side of me sees that as nitpicky, since I doubt women would really take offense to it any more than, say,  the word "manhole"... it's more a language tradition than anything. However, if people *were* offended by it, I suppose "Good Sport" would be a suitable alternative.

Comment: This badge should also be able to be awarded multiple times to encourage continued sportsmanlike behavior.

Comment: @Bill: Good idea. It could be awarded at 100-upvote intervals.

Comment: It has two flaws. First, it can encourage adding noise to SO by adding a useless (not downvote worthy but useless) answer to questions with good answers and upvoting them. Second, which is more important IMO, is that it'll discourage deleting *noisy* answers (e.g. dupe answer in a small time frame). The latter behavior is pretty common among high rep users and shouldn't be discouraged.

Comment: @Richard: How about a "PC Mad" badge for 10+ edits changing he to he/she or him to him/her etc :p

Comment: @Mehrdad: You made two good points, but I think they are of minimal concern. First of all, requiring a threshold of 100 (maybe more) non-wiki upvotes means a user would have to make a concerted effort adding "useless" answers and upvoting all the others. They'd need a few days to do this, since there is a limit on daily votes, and would likely be noticed. Also, adding so many "useless" answers will almost certainly garner some downvotes. Second, users who are already responsible enough to delete "noisy" answers will probably continue to do so, badge or no badge.

Comment: @Mehrdad - To combat this, you could require that _their_ answer be upvoted as well. So not only did they give a good answer, but they upvoted other people's good answers.

Comment: @Chris: Very good idea! I'm going to add it to the badge suggestion right now.

Comment: Should have a lesser Badge for 10 upvotes to other ansers, so as to get *new* users upvoting more.

Comment: "Team Player" or "Magnanimous" perhaps?

Comment: Why has this not been implemented yet?

Comment: @Chris: I guess they were busy implementing "careers". ;)

Comment: @Mehrdad: good point...say you up-vote 100 answers, and 50 of your own answers are up-voted???

Comment: I propose two additional constraints. 1) that the upvote for a competitor must be cast *before* an answer is selected by the OP. 2) only one upvote per question counts towards the badge. Otherwise, the system could be easily gamed. People could withhold their vote, check their profile page for new accepted answers, then upvote all competing (read: no longer competing) answers in bulk. Also, many users could get the badge (many times over) on the very day it is introduced, simply by going through their accepted answers and thoughtlessly upvoting everyone. The rich could instantly get richer.

Comment: @RedDwight: A couple counter-points: 1) Accepted answers aren't set in stone. I've seen them changed quite a few times, so other answers are still technically "in the game", and upvoting them has a chance to lose you an acceptance. 2) Users are limited to 30 votes per day, which will limit how quickly they could get the badge. The number of votes needed to get the badge could also be increased to make it harder to get by thoughtless upvoting. 3) I doubt the badge would be more than a silver, so I don't think people will be so desperate to get it as to burn through all their votes for days.

Comment: @gnostradamus: great counter-points, all three of them. I feel especially dumb for not having thought about the second one. Thanks for taking the time to address my concerns.

Comment: Dear lord, if this were re-calced to include all votes, I'd probably get it a half dozen times.

Comment: Carebear? Shouldn't be awarded multiple times though

Comment: @Jeff: this badge suggestion has more than twice the votes of any others, you even said it's a good one yourself over a year ago... do you think there's any chance we'll see it soon?

Comment: OMG. I just thought about this very idea and thought about exactly the same name, only to see it as the top answer :P

Comment: [status-completed] http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/vote-early-vote-often/

Answer (score 88):

**Great Voter** — For voting 3000 times

**Electorate** — For voting 30000 times

The basic currency of the Stack Overflow is reputation earned by votes. To encourage the reputation system to function, we should encourage more upvoting by the silent majority.
Currently there is only one badge called Civic Duty for voting 300 times. Why not expand this?

Comment: +1 I totally agree. Voting is what drives the site, and there is little motivation once you pass 300, except for the good of the community. Also, perhaps a name like "Senator" or "Chancellor"? (Hey, how comes there's no "vote of no confidence"?)

Comment: Maybe make 30k -> 10k... it would take unrealistically long to get to 30k

Comment: I think Civic Duty is good enough for this purpose.

Comment: +1 for a good idea, -1 because I hate Regan and the phrase he originated ("silent majority").

Comment: I like this idea...  except 3k is a lot!  Maybe 1k?

Comment: see new badge [Electorate] http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8376/how-to-encourage-voting-on-questions/8389#8389

Comment: @Jeff Atwood nice!

Answer (score 84):

Some ideas (some serious, some not so):

- `Recursive Badge` - Awarded for gaining the `Recursive Badge`
- `Poet Badge` - Awarded for getting 3 upvotes on an answer given in the form of Haiku
- `Voyeur Badge` - For those that like to watch. Viewed 1000 questions without participating in any manner (answering, commenting, voting, etc)
- `Communist Badge` - Every question/answer given marked as community wiki
- `Capitalist Badge` - Only answering questions with a bounty
- `Self-esteem Badge` - Gold badge awarded to everyone, because everyone's a winner!

Comment: +1 for self-esteem badge, made me laugh.

Comment: "You get a badge, and you get a badge... badges for everyone!"

Comment: Answers in haiku / That's a little too obscure / Who's gonna do that?

Comment: Well played Graeme Perrow / Your haiku is alluring / Challenge it I must!

Comment: Is "Graeme" one syllable or two?

Comment: I was guessing one, but I could be wrong. =)

Comment: I like the voyeur, communist & capitalist badges.

Comment: I like the Recursive Badge because it so belongs on StackOverflow

Comment: Capitalist discourages users from answering *other* questions. Voyeur would be hard to track.

Comment: Sorry guys, Graeme is two syllables (sounds like Graham). I wrote this one a while ago: "Haiku can be tough / you have to count syllables / this one is wrong"

Comment: Funny, I pronounce "Graham" like "gram". Oh well, I guess I deserve a "Haiku Facepalm" badge now. ;)

Comment: (Going way off-topic here) A lot of people pronounce my name like "Gram", including my own kids. :-(  It's pronounced "GRAY-um". And Graeme with "eme" rather than "ham" is a alternate Scottish spelling. I've had people ask me "are you sure?" when I spell it for them.

Comment: Composing haikus / is easy. Just stop at the / seventeenth syllab

Comment: Ok. These are kind of funny, but I actually think each of proposed badges is a bad idea. A badge should encourage some positive behavior, and I can't see the case for any of these.

Comment: That poet badge has me thinking. How to write a Regex to detect a haiku? hmmmm..

Comment: @JohnFx: Being into regexes is like having a Dremel (rotary drive) tool - you see everything in terms of how you can apply your cool <s>toy</s>tool.  Regexes cannot reliably count syllables.

Comment: @Argalatyr - What _can_ reliably count syllables? Apparently even us people who are intelligent enough to speak the language can't correctly count the syllables in Graeme's name.

Comment: The genius of the Recursive badge is that it has no base case to terminate the recursion.  Therefore, should anybody actually acquire the badge it would cause a... Stack Overflow.  The concept is so meta that it blows my mind.

Comment: dagnabbit where's my `[Poet]` badge??

Comment: @Anton lol (and I'm oldschool, I mean it)

Comment: @Dan it would only cause an SO if it didn't use tail recursion :D

Comment: Commun- and Capitalist can easily be made to work: just count.  Award Capitalist for N (won?) bounty answers.  Communist for N question/answers made community wiki.  And voyeur: N viewed questions.  Maybe N per day for M days in a row?  The possibilities are endless.

Comment: Oh, and the Recursive badge... I'd love to just see it in the list of badges, the obvious joke being that no-one will ever attain it.

Comment: none of these actually encourage desired behaviors...

Comment: `Tautology Badge` - You can only have this badge if you already have it

Comment: @Earlz---your Tautology Badge is recursive, though.  See http://xkcd.com/703/

Comment: @OP:  Capitalist and Communist badge criteria are too extreme. What about grades and/or a quantity? E.g. for Capitalist: 10 questions---Greenhorn Bounty Hunter, 50 questions---Boushh Award, 100 Bounties---Boba Fett Trophy.

Comment: @Mark, yes but the recursion is less obvious.

Comment: the recursive badge should be given to those who tag their question with `recursion`

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=recursion

Comment: Which of these are serious?

Comment: @Tomas - At the time I wrote this (4 years ago!?!) I had intended the capitalist/communist ones as seeds of serious ideas (although the specifics I gave are too extreme), but then as I was writing, I think I got a bit carried away with the "some not so" ones. :)

Answer (score 84):

**Noted** - user profile viewed 1000 times

**Prominent** - user profile viewed 5000 times

**Renowned** - user profile viewed 20,000 times

Comment: 20K views? That's a long way down the road. Even Mr. Atwood only has 8K right now.

Comment: He only shows up on SO about once a week.  Most of the more prominent users are well over 10k.  Anyway, the numbers aren't really the point.

Comment: 1k- Noted, 3k- Prominent, 5k- Renowned... the numbers aren't really the point. :)

Answer (score 65):

Architect - awarded to a user who has an idea implemented.

I guess it would have to be a manually awarded badge - but highly prized.

Comment: I really like this idea as it encourages people to come up with good/unique ideas for improvement.

Comment: It also encourages people to suggest ideas in the first place; probably the same ones over and over as new users come in.

Comment: In what context? Idea for the site, or idea for the answer? For the former, how can you implement an idea without access to the code, and for the latter, who decides if the idea was implemented - high-rep users?

Comment: It seems to me like it would be a meta badge. If your suggestion is implemented it would be awarded to you.

Comment: see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17985/encouraging-feature-requests

Comment: @nagul: I think it becomes a subjective badge actually - awarded to the person who proposed the idea. The idea should at least be given an upvote and selected as an answer. The OP should then provide an update in the text of their question showing some sort of snippet in how the idea was implemented. The *architect* of the idea then should be able to be nominated by the OP to gain the badge. Then it becomes a community vote, therefore subjective. That is just an idea on how the badge could be earned legitimately.

Answer (score 62):

Name suggested by [Quinn Taylor](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/130179/quinn-taylor): **Smart Upstart/Underdog**

You got an accepted answer where a rival answer was submitted by somebody with X times more reputation that you.

Comment: This is somewhat dependent on Jon Skeet always being a prominent user, right?  Not that it doesn't appear that way - just playing devil's advocate.

Comment: It was more of a fun idea ;)

Comment: You could award it for when a rival answer was submitted by someone with a much higher reputation than your own.

Comment: last one is good, makes it more serious as well.

Comment: And makes a lot of badges.

Comment: While skeet is a great guy, I don't think the community should ever start operating around his persona.

Comment: Apple's WWDC has a traditional panel called "Stump the Experts". Maybe something like "Smart Upstart" or "Underdog"?

Comment: Nice, I like Underdog

Comment: Just a joke, I'll change it.

Comment: "... submitted by *something* with x amount times more reputation than you"??? Are you implying that inhuman creatures are infiltrating SO? =)

Comment: I wouldn't just use a plain multiple - as it'd be too easy to get the badge when you've got a small reputation, so I might use 'x * reputation + c' or perhaps 'max(x * reputation, c)', and I'd make 'c' pretty large.

Comment: Needs to be called "Grasshopper"

Comment: I like the name "underdog" as well.

Comment: (-1) On SO, everyone should be giving the best answer they can. We shouldn't be operating on a 'tier' system. You should answer a question when you think no one else has it right, their reputations should not matter.

Comment: @devinb I doubt people intentionally gives lousy answers on SO. This badge would be likely to incentivize users with less rep to post good answers in the hope of earning a badge for giving a *better* answer than a much more experienced/reputable user. I can't really see a downside to something like this...

Comment: Interesting idea: a badge that Jon Skeet can't get!

Comment: Oh, he'll find a way...

Comment: @Graeme Perrow  maybe that badge should be called beat-skeet?

Comment: I would add a minimum score on the answer (e.g. 3) to prevent too easy gaming.

Answer (score 56):

***Premium (paid) Badges***

1. These can be purchased via Pay Pal for $49.99
2. Always appear first in the list of badges
3. Shiny color (animated gif should do the trick)
4. Only viewable by the recipient (that's the sweetest part)

Comment: Should it be called the "My Precious" badge and be ring-shaped?

Comment: @Arnis L.: now that's ^ better!

Comment: That is a site support badge. haha

Comment: Will there be an executive version of these badges for $149.99 with a gold border and mahogany background?

Comment: Makes sense if you can already buy/sponsor tags! ...cough... Adobe

Comment: Call it "Franklin Mint"

Comment: @Jay are they *still* in business?

Comment: or you could greasemonkey it in about 5 minutes.

Comment: As an alternative fo "My Precious" I propose to call this Ibadge "I am rich" - just to be more app oriented... Also please up the price to about $1000 ^_^

Answer (score 54):

Two serious ones:

**Big Day** -- capped out on rep in a given day

**Quality Poster** -- (pick your metrics but let's say) last twenty answers yielded 50 upvotes, at least 4 accepted answers, and no downvotes

I really believe in a Quality Poster badge.  Would help distinguish professionals from rep-whores.

And how about

**Curmudgeon** -- last 100 votes, more down than up

Comment: I like quality poster it promotes high quality answers.

Comment: Isn't the Big Day basically a Jon Skeet badge? I don't think he's ever failed to hit the cap. As a one-time-only bronze badge, it might be useful, though, since it would stop new users from asking "Why didn't I get rep from my last three upvotes?"

Comment: As for the quality poster, that would be rather hard to get. I say that because in my last twenty answers, I have 96 upvotes, 8 accepted answers, and 2 downvotes. It's hard to not have a single downvote -- unless you post so many answers a day that the random week-later up and downvotes don't affect your last twenty answers (twenty answers ago for me was June 20), and you avoid saying anything even mildly controversial in the first place.

Comment: @mmyers: not sure exactly what the metrics should be for Quality badge, but it should be hard to earn

Comment: Hard I can understand (and I'm in favor of), but there's no way to control downvotes. Those two downvotes were both on answers to ambiguously-worded questions; the downvoters apparently had a different interpretation than I did.

Comment: @mmyers: unquestionably true.  But most badges are earned on poster whim:  Famous Question, Great Answer, Populist; anything that's vote- or view-based.  This would just be the first that incorporated a down-vote factor.

Comment: +1 for Curmudgeon in some form. The name is too good. :-)

Comment: @John Pirie - for those badges you mentioned, "poster whim" aggregates over time though.  Having a "no downvotes" criteria would really harm the Quality badge concept.  I've seen people come into a question and downvote every single answer for no discernible reason. It also opens the potential badge earner to easy sabotage.

Comment: @mmeyers: I don't think it's that hard to not get down votes. When I do get down votes, I usually anticipated it ahead of time. Of course, if you know you are going to get more down votes than up votes, you probably shouldn't post.

Comment: I think Big Day could be awarded on the first time. But I DO NOT like "Quality Poster". It encourages users to answer CERTAIN questions, instead of contributing to as many questions as possible. Generally, we want users to provide answers wherever they have something useful to say. So, I might disagree with an accepted answer, but I might not post, because I really want that "Quality Poster" badge. That is not behaviour we would want to encourage.

Comment: wordweb - curmudgeon: "a crusty irascible cantankerous old person full of stubborn ideas".  good one :).

Comment: @devinb - It encourages users to contribute to the best of their ability and give the most accurate answers possible. It discourages bad or incorrect answers. If you post a better answer to a question with a bad accepted answer, it will often get voted up a lot (and sometimes accepted - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597405/what-happens-to-a-declared-uninitialized-variable-in-c-does-it-have-a-value). And 50 rep from 20 posts is easy. That's an average of 2.5 upvotes per post. You don't need a stunningly brilliant answer, you just need the right one (and being quick couldn't hurt).

Comment: [Mortarboard](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/144/mortarboard) is now implemented for Big Day.

Answer (score 50):

There are several badges related to having an accepted answer (Scholar, Enlightened, Guru) but none that relate to **achieving a certain threshold of accepted answers**. For example, knowing somebody has had 10/50/100 answers accepted would increase my confidence that they know what they're talking about (not just throwing out lots of mildly helpful answers over time), and is yet another way to reward people who provide an excellent answer.

Here are a few name ideas such badges...

- Aficionado
- Master
- Philosopher
- Pundit
- Sage
- Savant

In speaking with the SO team about this earlier, they suggested that "there's a 'rich get richer' problem with this style of award." I can see how that can certainly happen, but I see it in a different way...

**People who strive to provide good answers in less-popular tags** (such as Cocoa and Objective-C, like I do) **will likely never get enough votes/views/favorites to earn most of the popularity-related badges**. In contrast, an "N accepted answers" badge can be earned through technical knowledge and helpfulness, without being tied to a popular technology. (Or posting a subjective/controversial/funny question/answer, whether intentionally or not.)

Of course, if knowledgeable people start answering every question just to "level up" on accepted answers, I can see how newer members can feel left out. However, I (like to) think most people aren't prone to abuse the system that way, and more good answers does benefit the community as a whole.

Comment: I totally agree with your reasoning regarding less-popular tags. For me, it's rare to find MATLAB answers with more than 10 votes, hence "Nice Answer" or "Enlightened" badges are hard to come by (I only have 1 of each for all the MATLAB answers I've given).

Comment: I hear what you're saying, but this badge would have massive side effect of badge inflation for all the popular topics. Big big downside.

Comment: @Jeff - I understand the point about inflation, but how bad would this be?  There can only be one accepted answer per question, so with 200k questions on the site.. if the threshold was set at 100 accepted answers, we're talking maximum 2000 badges awarded, and probably much less than that?  I'd really like to see a couple more badges around the "accepted answer" functionality. It's important that really specific or niche questions get the help they seek, and the system currently doesn't really encourage answering questions that might not attact much attention.

Comment: A scaling factor related to the number of questions in the category would help ease the inflation effect for popular categories

Comment: Must find others name for "Master", "Sage" and "Savant" badges because they are "Rank" for "Experts" on Experts-Exchange.

Comment: @Jeff How about awarding the badge for answers on questions with tags with under X questions in total? That would solve the problem right.

Answer (score 47):

**Chart Topper** - asked the most up-voted question (and/or answer) that week, it should be awarded multiple times.

Comment: I like this one as well!

Comment: Wiki questions excluded?

Answer (score 45):

Frustration badge: 5+ answers accepted before hitting the daily rep limit.

Over-and-above badge: contributing significant extra content in an answer after it's already been accepted, but only if the answer then gets another 5 upvotes (to avoid just mindless padding).

Comment: lol at the first the second is kind of a self-beating populist - nice ;-p

Comment: I like the "over & above" idea.

Comment: Or for getting a 300-point bounty first thing in the morning ;-p

Comment: @Marc: Yes indeed :)

Comment: @Marc/Jon... who defines "morning?"

Comment: @Rob: UTC, of course. Even if I were residing elsewhere, the day would still start when the rep cap ticked over :)

Comment: Frustration badge is now moot with the new rep calc algorithm.

Answer (score 43):

**Bounty Hunter** — Given the first time your answer is accepted for a bountied question. Generally they're harder to answer anyway. (Or as @Alconja suggested with Capitalist, for answering only bountied questions, something like that.)

---

**Edit:** Just found [this related MSO question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1182/bounty-hunter-badges), and of course the idea [originated from Jon Skeet](http://stackoverflow.uservoice.com/pages/1722-general/suggestions/110435-bounty-hunter-badges). How could I expect otherwise? ;-)

Answer (score 41):

**Badger**—awarded when someone continually requests new badges on Meta.

Comment: And can be awarded multiple times... Badger Badger Badger!

Comment: hahaha, I like this one.

Comment: +1 hahaha!!! loved it. don't have enough rep to upvote you

Comment: @Veer: did you link your account with whatever site you came from?

Comment: @veer: You *should* link it -- the reason I ask is that when I linked my account here on meta with my SO account, I got a 100 rep bonus, which is enough to upvote stuff.

Comment: @SamB Ya i linked it. But didn't get any rep bonus. But i got it for other accounts.

Comment: @SamB Ha! i got it! I cleared all the associations and linked them again. Thanks!

Comment: Badger?  We don't need no stinking badgers!

Comment: We need a mushroom and snake badge too.

Answer (score 39):

**Unselfishness** — For people who consistently post good answers in obscure or low-view tags.

Despite the joking about Objective-C fanboys, one of the perennial frustrations is that so few people view or vote on questions in that tag. My highest-voted SO answer was (still is) a semi-flippant one to a question with a Java tag. :-/

Sure, we post for a given language because we love it and/or use it all the time, but also because we care to help other users of the language. Nobody's hating on the Java or C# dudes, probably because they're in the majority, but does that necessarily make one any less of a fanboy? :-)

Comment: Maybe we need a list of some overlooked tags; I'd happily peruse a few to watch (and vote) for general quality of the Qs&As - although I'm not qualified to comment on technical accuracy.

Comment: Yeah, but moderators shouldn't have to artificially inflate the stats for our pathetic little tags. :-) It should really come from the people who benefit from the tag, although getting people to vote (well) is tough.

Comment: what if lower use tags had some way (trigger, threshold) of dishing bonus rep for accepted or up-voted answers?

Comment: Good idea, but I think this speaks more to getting people to vote, than force-rewarding the the heroes.

Answer (score 35):

Super Hero - 500+ points in 24 hours or having 10 answers accepted in 24 hours, either way showing super human (answering) abilities.

Comment: Call it the Jack Bauer badge.

Comment: Last time I looked, there was a 200 points per day limit.

Comment: @jamesh: Points gained by having answers accepted still count, even if you've already reached the 200-point limit.

Comment: @jamesh - not so; the high rep uses are often at 300+/day. I don't know if I've done 500 (I've come close a few times, though, even without bounty), but sounds like a fun challenge ;-p

Comment: 500 points in 24 hours could be 200 points just before UTC midnight, then 200 points + 105 from 7 correct answers in the first part of the next day. It could happen :) (FWIW, without bounty I've never reached 500 in a UTC day. My best was 425 on March 31st, I think. Including bounties: 556 on April 2nd with a 150 bounty.)

Comment: Is this really how the cap works right now? I've definitely lost points due to getting accepts+bounty before I hit 200 then...

Comment: @annakata - yes, that is correct. Frustrating, isn't it? Jon had a 300 bounty accepted the other day... first thing in the morning ;-p

Comment: I would suggest something more reasonable like 250 points (probably because I got 260 a few times... :)

Comment: Call it the Jon Skeet badge.

Comment: Naw, the Skeet badge should be given to those who had given an accepted answer to a question Jon asked.

Answer (score 32):

**The Long-Haul Trucker.**

For "clearing the road" of tumbleweeds.

Answered `n` [Tumbleweeded](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/38/tumbleweed) questions with at least one upvote.

Comment: Sounds cool... kind of along the lines of the Necromancer badge, but for unpopular as opposed to old questions.

Comment: funny - I go through the tumbleweeded questions every week or two :)

Answer (score 28):

**Rockefeller / Gates** - You have to buy it, and it costs 20k in reputation

Comment: CoD prestige mode.

Comment: Rep sinks, sounds like a great idea.

Comment: I like the idea of buying badges with rep. Very interesting.

Comment: Jon Skeet wouldn't buy it just to spite us all.

Comment: Yeah, but all the badge whores would, making it easier for the rest of us to identify and ignore them.

Comment: Pynt: Jon Skeet would buy it and still hit the daily rep cap.

Comment: @Tom: lol...I wonder if I could get a rep loan to get that badge...do we have a 20 year mortgage available?

Comment: booooo!! :D ...

Answer (score 26):

**Centennial Badge**: visited the site each day for 100 years.

Comment: /me tries to picture Jon Skeet at age 133... then regrets it.

Comment: /me pictures Jon Skeet right now... then regrets it. :P

Comment: while cute - it'd be more interesting to extend the **fanatic** badge to someone who keeps up for a year

Comment: there can be a badge for maximum number of visits. should be like a rolling trophy

Answer (score 25):

Troll - 100+ down votes

Comment: heh, great badge to show off ;) or most likely, to warn people ;)

Comment: I like the concept of negative badges - for the good of the community

Comment: Negative badges should come in their own flavor...  not bronze, silver, or gold...  they should be plastic or rust.  Some cheesy ugly badge color that you don't want

Comment: Skull and Cross bones or bio hazard.

Comment: White Skull and cross bones, in a black circle, or rectangle.

Comment: A *ratio* of downvotes would be more appropriate. I'm fairly certain that high volume users have way past 100 downvotes, but compare that to the number of upvotes... Also, heavily downvoted items are often deleted, making the numbers harder. Perhaps a count of the number of items closed as spam/offensive...

Comment: I don't think a 'negative' badge is a good idea. It's still a collectable, shiny or not, and (some) people will want to have one. They would encourage negative behaviour.

Comment: I'd actually like to see this badge for people with an high ratio of downvotes *cast*

Comment: See the post by John Pirie — I like the idea of "Curmudgeon" for high ratio of downvotes cast.

Comment: Darn. Blorgbeard is right unfortunately...

Comment: I've got 599 downvotes... but 1458 upvotes... I don't think I'd deserve a Troll badge. So, yes, ratio.

Comment: @Jeff Fritz: How about fuchsia? :-)

Comment: Aren't "Tumbleweed" and "Peer Pressure" already badges of dubious honor?

Comment: Down/Up > 1 == Troll && Down/Up < 0.5 == Cheerleader

Comment: How about giving it to anyone with a ratio greater than or equal to that of Rich B?

Comment: perhaps negative badges should be taken away after a period of non-infringement

Comment: @Quinn, tumbleweed is something that happens *to you*. And Peer Pressure encourages you to remove noise from the site.

Comment: (-1) I don't feel that negative badges are advisable on StackOverflow. As Jeff Atwood has mentioned, once a badge is given, it is never removed. That means that you will always be branded with whatever negative stigma is associated with the badge. And most behaviours that are numerable will EVENTUALLY be reached by the power users. I have quite a lot of downvotes, and quite a lot of upvotes too. I don't think I should be branded for that.

Comment: i do, at least temporarily.  the badge simply describes what kind of user you are.  if you're a harsh critical cynic, then maybe the badge system should reflect that

Comment: I'm very proud I recently earned the Peer pressure badge

Comment: Troll is not a good name for such a badge.  Maybe "Cynic" or "Glass Half Empty" or something similar.

Comment: I have downvoted 153 times and I'm not a troll.

Comment: (-1) Not the best idea - downvoting is one of the means by which we weed out patently-bad suggestions (as opposed to suggestions that you merely dont feel earn an upvote). The ratio of downvotes to upvotes might be more meaningful, but Troll isn't a suitable name. I like Dans suggestions, but I'm sure there are others...

Comment: @Quinn - I've never viewed it that way. I always had tumbleweed pegged as noone being able to answer/seeing the question, and peer pressure as removing a bad answer from the sight of others (aka. removing noise).

Answer (score 25):

Greengrocer - 10 unreverted edits to other people's posts that merely remove apostrophes. (See [Greengrocer's apostrophe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostrophe#Greengrocers.27_apostrophes))

Comment: I love this suggestion + I do it a lot!

Comment: Or insert the missing ones?  (Not "one's", please note.)

Comment: +1 just for the link -- i never knew about that.

Comment: ++++ hard to code, but brilliant!

Comment: LOL --> *Dunglish*

Comment: Wouldn't Greengrocer be more appropriate for people who'd had a number of such edits performed on *there* posts?

Answer (score 25):

**Hacker** -- This badge is never given out, the only people who have it have hacked the system.

Comment: You mean the Hacker9asdasijhd187bcb87caisbcab17c18qcn89anascNOPNOPNOP... badge?

Comment: Hacker, in these parts, is more likely to be awarded to someone who has done excellent work on the implementation of Stack Overflow. 1337 h4x0r, on the other hand ...

Comment: Same idea but "Black Spot" in a pirate theme to people that misuse the site somehow.

Answer (score 22):

**Narcissist** - accept 10 of your own answers (must have up votes)

Comment: Hey, sometimes you just know who has the best answer, right? ;-)

Comment: I do this (though it may not get upvotes), on grounds that sometimes the answer reached is inspired by, but very different to, the answers I received.  I'll upvote the inspiration(s) and then accept the solution I actually used.

Comment: I've answered a few of my questions simply b/c I found an answer or derived one from another source when none of the other answers would pan out.

Answer (score 20):

**I-Shot-The-Sheriff**

Awarded when your answer, submitted after one from a moderator, is accepted.  Could be awarded multiple times.

Comment: Haha, funny.  I like it.

Comment: Hey now, as a moderator I'd like to point out that out answers are perfect, every time.  OK, maybe not always.  :) +1

Comment: Re; the Jon Skeet award...actually...hhmmm - what about if an answer is accepted from a poster with significantly less rep than another...both answers must have at least 3 or 5  up-votes?

Comment: @mrdenny: your comments certainly don't appear to be! (I hope you can't fix that typo after all this time and make me look dumb :-).

Answer (score 19):

**Chatter Box** - ratio of comments to answers is 10:1 or above.

Comment: I'm probably pretty close to that on SO (and I bet many would have this on MSO).

Answer (score 19):

**Compulsive Voter** —  For those of us who consistently use up our daily votes.

This obviously has negative incentives for stuffing the ballot box, usually with upvotes. I see it more as a humorous badge, anyway.

Comment: I just had to give that +1.

Comment: There's a limit?

Comment: This is now implemented as the [Suffrage badge](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/118/suffrage) (for the first time, at any rate).

Answer (score 18):

Now that there is linking between accounts on the different sites, what about cross site badges:

- **Programmer** - awarded for having greater than some amount of rep on SO
- **Server Admin** - awarded for having greater than some amount of rep on SF
- **Metahead** - (or some answer from [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1120)) awarded for having greater than some amount of rep on meta
- **Power user** - awarded for having greater than some amount of rep on SU

While naming is certainly important, it is not my talent, so liberties should be taken with these names and the amount of rep would need to be determined, but I would think something like 5k maybe.

To be clear, my thought is these would be badges visible on all sites, so if you earn it on SO, it would be listed under your badges on SF, etc.

Comment: we already have that by folks becoming moderators at 10k, right?

Comment: How about only being able to possess one of these badges at any one time, but you get it on all sites. The one you get corresponds to the site where you have the most rep (above a minimum threshold).

Comment: I like the idea. It would be nice to show people in what domain you're better.

Comment: @Æther: Bad idea, IMHO. If someone has the potential to earn more than one of these badges, I think they should be able to possess all of them for which they qualify. Maybe have bronze/silver/gold level badges, with the next level up replacing the lower level one, to show a user's relative level of participation on each site.

Comment: @Ether: I'm with @RobH.

Answer (score 18):

**Policeman** - was first to flag posts/questions that were later removed as hate speech or trolling. Bronze (Policeman) - did it one time, Silver (Officer) - 30 times, Gold - (Inspector) - 100 times. Note [Marc Gravell's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15143/whats-with-all-the-rude-comments-recently/15168#15168) about need to flag rude post - this badge could make people to report unacceptable behaviour.

Comment: There is already a badge for flagging posts.

Comment: Yes, there is "Citizen patrol" but you get it for single flagging. I want to ensure people to report abuses often, so moderators can get SO free of abusers.

Comment: I suppose.  Having a badge for only one isn't super helpful. `+1`

Comment: I like it...   +1

Comment: Leave Citizen Patrol as the first one, then make Policeman 10, and Officer 50.

Answer (score 18):

**Unrewarded** Ten or more accepted answers with 0 or 1 upvotes. One for the people working in fringe badges or just those unlucky enough to answer during a quiet patch for upvoting.

**Inquisitive** 90% of activity is questions (maybe on 10 consecutive days to make the percentage workable over time)

**Helpful** 90% of activity is answers (with durational requirement as above)

**Balanced Diet** Percentage of answers and questions very close.

Comment: I like "Unrewarded" as a consolation prize for not getting (presumably) good questions upvoted, if it were restricted to answers with only zero votes. However, almost everyone will end up getting at least one of the other three badges, which would render them fairly pointless.

Comment: Good point about those badges going to almost everyone, perhaps more restrictive criteria? 95%? I think there is something to be said for badges that server as statistical measures - how many people are there who pretty much only answer questions? Though, maybe it doesn't server the other purpose of driving desirable behaviour.

Comment: Why not add a minimum count to Inq and Help?  Otherwise, one answer in 10 days would get you the badge.

Comment: The duration requirement was intended to refer to a grand total percent, not to the spot average. So I was thinking 90% of all time activity is questions, over n days) however, thinking about this, it wouldn't be necessary since once rewarded, badges are not removed.

Comment: +1 for Unrewarded - I've got 35 accepted SO answers with <=1 vote... Think this works around the issue of inflation in major tags mentioned elsewhere in relation to accepted answer badges.

Comment: "Unrewarded" is good. I was thinking of it as "Unsung Hero". Getting an answer accepted with no upvotes feels like it was just grudgingly accepted by the inquirer.

Comment: @Rob Heiser: I like "Unsung Hero" as well.

Answer (score 16):

I think "Member of all SO sites" would be nice, but I would change it to 'Participant', i.e. asked/answered at least 1 question in each site.

Comment: all is relative to the time frame though.  There was a time not that long ago that everyone would get this badge for only being on stackoverflow.com

Comment: Good      idea.

Comment: Is that asked *or* answered, or asked *and* answered?

Answer (score 16):

**Cited**: — if your answer is cited (*linked to*) more than 10/50/100 times, perhaps only from answer with at least one upvote. This is to encourage comprehensive answers that are referred to.

Might be difficult to implement, and to tune: number of citations is a free parameter, requirements on grade of answer with citation (points / number of upvotes).

Comment: What if you're the one linking?

Comment: @mmyers , just do not account links made by you.  And lover the threshold needed to gain the badge.

Comment: Maybe have different levels. (Bronze == cited, silver == highly cited, gold == ??.) Someone would have to come up with better names.

Comment: Gold = textbook author? I like this particularly if you garner a lot of attention from search engines too (can they be counted in?)

Answer (score 16):

**Weekend Warrior**

Posted an accepted answer to a question on weekend.

This badge could only be awarded once.

Since traffic and responses are MUCH lower on weekends, this would maybe reward those that post and troll on the weekends helping out others.

Comment: I like this, except it's hard to define "weekend" given the variation in timezones. Australians could nail this one on Monday morning while it's still Sunday UTC.

Comment: If we define WE as Saturday and Sunday... well, WE would be from when the last TZ enters Saturday to when the first TZ enters Monday. So, about 24 hours, IINM.

Answer (score 15):

**Fast gun** Posting an answer within a minute of the question being asked, that gets accepted without any edits.

**Edit**: Answering your own question wouldn't count. That'd be shooting yourself in the foot.

**Update**: Turns out this is a duplicate of [New Badge: Quick-Draw](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1289/new-badge-quick-draw/60662).

Comment: not just a *fast* gun.. you'd be the **Fastest Gun in the West** (although that's a bit long)

Comment: "Fast gun" earned me a necromancer badge. The irony!

Comment: LOL @ the edit. Maybe there should also be a badge for shooting yourself in the foot. (Kidding.)

Comment: That badge is impossible to get since question can take from 30 seconds to 2 minute to show up because of the cache on SO.

Comment: @HoLyVieR: That'd still give you 30 seconds to answer!

Answer (score 14):

**Hot Streak** - name for [Damien](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/35454/damien) idea

> Something for posting an accepted
>   anwser once a day for 15-30 days.
>   Don't know what you could call it..

Comment: I would call it the ZOMFG badge

Answer (score 13):

**Home Run** - Hit the rep cap just from one answer (or question) posted that same day.

Comment: How often does that happen? Do you have to be answering a question on regexes and HTML?

Comment: @Andrew - no idea.  Not often I'd say.  But it might be a fun thing to aim at...

Comment: I think it's fairly common, though I suspect we'd just be piling reward on top of reward at that point

Comment: @Jeff that might only be common on SO, since on SU I only expect a couple of users to reach that :-(

Answer (score 11):

**Scientist** - upvoting X number of *questions* where:

- you've provided an answer that received at least one upvote, and
- you upvote at least one other answer

both of which happened before an answer was accepted.

If the user answered the question, received an upvote for the answer, and then deleted it, that should also count.  Presumably they learned something from a better answer, just like a real scientist.

The concept behind this badge is mainly to encourage the upvoting of questions more often.  The restrictions would be to prevent random upvoting.

Comment: See "sportsman" suggestion.

Comment: I saw it.  The mechanism here is close, except that you must be upvoting questions, rather than just upvoting other answers.  And of course it's open to debate.

Answer (score 11):

**Life is Hard** - First time you get an answer accepted and later unaccepted (of course own questions don't count).

Comment: I would have won this several times over already!

Comment: Alternative name possibility - `"S**t Happens"` ;)

Answer (score 10):

**Inciter** - answer or question that generated 50+ comments

Suggested revision:

1. **Encourager** (bronze) received 10 or more comments on a single question or answer with a score greater than or equal to 1.
2. **Provocateur** (silver) received 25 or more comments on a single question or answer with a score greater than or equal to 5.
3. **Instigator** (gold) received 100 or more comments on a single question or answer with a score greater than or equal to 10.

In all cases, your own comments wouldn't count.

Comment: 50+ comments are probably a bad thing, aren't they?

Comment: Maybe a MSO badge only???

Comment: The problem is, you are creating a badge of honour for the trolls...

Comment: True, and "incite" generally has a negative connotation.

Comment: @sth Not if you combine it with the requirement that the question has a positive score.

Comment: I have added suggested revisions, but am keeping the original in place.

Answer (score 10):

Some comments on an answer end up collecting several up votes of their own.  Some badges based on "great" comments would be nice.

"Preaching to the choir" - x upvotes on a comment

Comment: Can't actually downvote a comment, last I saw ...

Comment: @a_mOd, I would have downvoted your comment, but I couldn't ;-)

Comment: I've been a fan of a badge for 100 upvotes on a comment -- ever since I got 100 upvotes on a comment. *whistles*

Comment: Doh! missed the fact that you can't downvote a comment...

Answer (score 10):

Something for posting an accepted anwser once a day for 15-30 days. Don't know what you could call it..

Comment: Good idea. See "Hot Streak", as someone called it in a higher-voted answer.

Answer (score 10):

**OCD** - visited the site every day for a year.

Comment: That would be a good candidate for a "green silicon" (i.e. better than gold) badge!

Answer (score 10):

**Usurper**: Have an answer accepted for a question that had an accepted answer at the time you posted your answer.

and

**Thief**: Have an answer accepted for a question that had an accepted answer at the time you edited your answer. The first version of your edited answer must have been posted before the other previously accepted answer was accepted.

Not too hard to automate. Also encourages users to supply/improve answers to questions that already have accepted answers.

Comment: Unfortunately, it wouldn't work on bountied questions, though, since the accepted answer can't be changed on those.

Answer (score 10):

**Nonconformist**

I'd like to see a badge for answering questions in very *un*popular tags. This would encourage people to answer questions that are otherwise unlikely to get decent answers.

*Badge name:* Nonconformist is intended to be somewhat an opposite of Generalist (but not in the direction of what could be called Specialist), with the added idea of "not conforming" to the popular tags.  What other names could be used for "helpful to *un*popular tags"?

Comment: I'd go for "spelunker".

Answer (score 10):

> **Usurper**
>   Posted an answer 6 months after an accepted one, resulting in the question owner switching to yours.

*Encourages posting better solutions when you come across old accepted answers.  Adjust time-scale to suit.*

Answer (score 10):

## Thesaurus

Suggest a tag synonym that is then accepted into the system.

Answer (score 9):

I raised a [feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13847/display-statistics-have-subject-badges-for-accepted-answers) before I saw this question for badges based on accepted answers in a tag. This would work similarly to the [tags badges for votes](https://stackoverflow.com/badges?tab=tags), but with a lower threshold, e.g. earn a silver badge for 100 accepted Java answers and gold for 250 accepted.

For example:

[.net accepted http://uvshock.co.uk/badges/badge.php?label=.net%20accepted&medal=gold](http://uvshock.co.uk/badges/badge.php?label=.net%20accepted&medal=gold)

[java accepted http://uvshock.co.uk/badges/badge.php?label=java%20accepted&medal=silver](http://uvshock.co.uk/badges/badge.php?label=java%20accepted&medal=silver)

etc.

Comment: I think having that would help show which users are contributing in certain tags.

Answer (score 9):

**Altruist** - Voted up an answer by someone else, on a question, that you yourself answered. You thought the other user's answer was better than your own answer.

You are unselfish, you are voting for the best answer for the good of the community, not to gain points. We like this type of behavior

Comment: *Hint:* Take a look at the top-voted answer to this question. ;)

Comment: NO. We like **points**!

Answer (score 9):

**Selfless** - For earning 100 (or 200 or whatever) rep over and above the rep cap on a given day.  Would encourage people who hit the rep cap on a day to continue answering questions even though they know that any additional up votes won't help their rep.

Comment: The Epic and Legendary badges lead to the same end.

Comment: @random - sort of, but not really.  They reward you for hitting the rep cap, but not for going "above and beyond".

Answer (score 9):

Weekend Warrior

Reaching rep cap on 13 Sundays.

---

Now with charts! (from [source](http://hewgill.com/~greg/stackoverflow/stack_overflow/stats.html))

[image]

Comment: sundays in .. what time zone? We can't do these :(

Comment: @Jeff: just pick a time zone. Maybe Saturday is better so it won't overlap on Monday.

Comment: Saturday in SO's timezone (UTC) would do.  Although, I'm not sure that adding more rep cap badges would add any value -- we'd see the same people getting them that already have hundreds (or thousands!) of badges.

Answer (score 9):

**Out Of Ammo** - Used all his/her votes for a day.

Comment: Up-voting is something to promote, but up-voting to get a badge ... I have a strong feeling that this would lead to people up-voting bad answer just for the badge.

Comment: This is a dupe of [a suggestion made a year earlier](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102/additional-badge-ideas/1264#1264). Kind of moot now though, it's been implemented as [Suffrage](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/118/suffrage).

Comment: @Popular Demand: Sorry. I didn't know it existed.

Answer (score 9):

**Great Mystery**

This badge is awarded for question having at least 5 up vote and at least 500 views and no up voted answer. This would award great question that the answer is unknown.

**World Mystery**

This is basicly the same as Great Mystery except that it would require at least 20 up vote, 1.5k view.

Answer (score 8):

**Controversy**

Question or answer voted up and down at least x times.

Comment: I suggested something like this back on UV, and the feedback was that they didn't want to create incentive for controversial posts.

Comment: That does make sense.

Answer (score 8):

How about something to encourage people to apply more effort to questions asked by users who don't often bother to accept answers to their questions?

**Thankless**

Answered a question posed by a user who has a worse than 20% accept rate, and that answer is voted up 10 times, is the top answer for the question by votes, and the asker doesn't accept any answer for the question for a month.

Comment: Interesting idea, but a lot of conditions in it.

Comment: Yeah, it's tricky, but it's not unusual for a low-accept-rate user to ask a question and -- despite the question occasionally being pretty good -- get a lot of snide remarks from commenters about their refusal to answer a question from someone who doesn't appreciate their answers.  I think it would benefit the community to have some of those answered, and a badge might help motivate people to answer even though there's little hope of getting a checkmark by your answer.

Answer (score 7):

**Beginners Luck** - accepted answer in the first 2 days of joining / or with you first ever answer.

Comment: except most of us could never get this since we're already here :(

Comment: not that I'm complaining, mind you :D

Answer (score 7):

**Burning the midnight oil**

Awarded for activity (vote, question, answer, comment) at least once per hour, for 24 hours in a row.

<strike>**Selfless** (or **Communist**, even if it was mentioned elsewhere)</strike>

First community wiki created (not turning a question into a community wiki, but really starting it as a wiki in the first place.)
 *(No longer relevant)*

<strike>**Elitist**</strike>

Has at least 50(?) Ignored Tags for every Interesting Tags (or has had that for x days).

**Renaissance Man**

Has had a high number(?) of Interesting Tags and no Ignored Tags for x days.

I really like how the last two play against each other :)
 *(I don't even remember what I meant)*

Addition:

**Train wreck**

Similar to a tumbleweed, with a twist: Asked a question with no votes, no answers, no comments, but high views (say 100), over any amount of time.

Comment: We don't want to encourage SO addiction ... at least officially. What about "graveyard shift" (or "Mumbai calling", or "always daytime in Iceland"), for answering questions in low-activity times though?

Comment: Definitely Graveyard Shift.

Comment: Selfless badge would also need to require a minimum number of votes on the question so that we don't inadvertently encourage bad cw questions.

Answer (score 6):

Didn't see the concept anywhere in these three pages...
**Radio Star**: awarded for asking a question that is singled out on the StackOverflow podcast (either by SO guys or guests)

Answer (score 6):

**Stalker** - For having more than 20 upvoted answers on different questions by the same user.  In other words, following someone around on SO answering their questions.

**Paparazzi** - For having more than 20 upvoted comments on different answers by the same user.

**Single** - For posting an accepted answer on February 14th.

Comment: What's the significance of 14 February?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valentines_day

Comment: How about "Single ton" - Gaining more than 100 rep on February 14th? http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ton#Noun

Comment: Well, I guess we know now that @random is single. No guy with a girlfriend or wife would be allowed to forget 2/14.

Comment: Being in a relationship has nothing to do with **love** (which is what is celebrated on valentines day) @gno @ran

Comment: @Downvoter: Love? I thought Valentine's Day was a celebration of chalky, antacid-like candies made from bone meal and earwig honey. ;) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweethearts_(candy)

Comment: @gnostradamus - they're not all chalky; some are waxy and some are chocolate.  (also: earwig honey??  eww...)

Comment: Wouldn't Stalker and Paparazzi encourage repwhore's to just create 2 accounts. One, to ask answer questions/comment, a second to upvote the first on everything.

Answer (score 6):

[Silver] **Silk purse** - Edited someone else's question with a negative vote count which later reaches a score of 2 or greater before it is edited again by anyone else.

Thanks Ether for the name.

Comment: "Made a Silk Purse from a Sow's Ear"? :)

Comment: "Plz help" if you're fixing obnoxious grammar?

Answer (score 5):

**Jack of All Trades** — amass a certain amount of rep (say, 1000) on each Trilogy site (excluding Meta).

You'd have to associate all your accounts to get this badge, but that's kind of the point.

Comment: Why exclude Meta?

Comment: ooh, keep an eye on http://stackexchange.com tomorrow. I'm just sayin'

Comment: 1000 on each trilogy site is recorded on [Stackathlon](http://stackathlon.appspot.com/).

Answer (score 5):

> **Referenced**
>   Post directly linked by 10 other questions or answers.

Comment: Not counting duplicate links?

Answer (score 5):

> **Donator**
>   Received *x* upvotes on wiki answers posted on non-wiki questions.

Comment: This is tricky to award because technically, there's no guarantee that your upvotes will be for that user's content. You could easily award this badge for "seed" answers.

Comment: @Grace: what are "seed" answers?

Comment: A seed answer would be the root from which a real answer grows. In other words, someone else might have posted the original answer, and as CW encourages other people to add their say, it evolves into a lovely answer that attracts many votes. Note that I don't think seed answers are bad - after all they yield good answers and are perfectly a good idea. But I think it kinda conflicts with what you might be intending for your badge (with a name like "Donator"). But I could be wrong, I could see a seed being a perfect setup of a donation, the first cent that starts a revolutionary benefit.

Comment: @Grace Note: I see now, that's a very good point. I hadn't thought about that, but the same is true of non-wiki answer badges like enlightened or great answer - those could have been edited by another user too. The badge name comes from the idea of not receiving anything in return (in this case, rep) when giving something away (knowledge), although I can see you got that :-)

Answer (score 5):

New idea.

We can have a badge called **Bounty Hunter** which will be given to a user who has answered some threshold number of bounty questions. Similar badges can be given if a user has asked some threshold number of bounty questions.

Comment: Already suggested - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1182/bounty-hunter-badges

Answer (score 5):

## Encyclopædian

Contribute to a tag wiki.

Answer (score 4):

`<obligatory>`
**Badges?  We don't need no stinkin' badges!**
`</obligatory>`

Part of the design of the system is that badges are *strictly* awarded for behaviour that we want to *encourage*.  "Odd, random criteria" would fall outside of that area.

That said, having a *tag* here on the meta site specifically for badge suggestions would be a great idea.

Answer (score 4):

As I suggested in [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1560/sidekick-badge), I think we should have a Sidekick badge for those who frequently contribute to upvoted or accepted answers via comments.

Comment: Though, of course, to be measurable... only accepted answers, and only if the comment came *before* it was accepted.  And maybe a max number of upvotes in relation to the next-higher voted answer (to avoid comment spam on very-highly-voted, and thus likely to be accepted answers)

Answer (score 4):

**A check from Knuth**: Being the first to find a bug and report it.

Other title suggestions welcome.

Comment: "Check for $2.56" is a bit shorter...

Comment: Or just "$2.56"

Answer (score 3):

The Misery Guts badge.

For people who've issued more downvotes than upvotes.  Do they really think that the majority of content on SO sucks?

Comment: Pointing out that an answer is wrong, is potentially more important than indicating the one correct answer is better than another correct answer. I don't think down votes should necessarily be discouraged.

Comment: Sturgeon's Law.

Comment: I respect downvoters, to a point.  50/50 seems about the limit.  But all upvotes feels too much like grade inflation.

Comment: @John, this could be a good application of "Curmudgoeon", which name I love. :-) I agree, good downvoting takes discipline, but sometimes it's just annoying. How about people who consistently downvote without offering constructive criticism?

Answer (score 3):

Fan Boy (or Fan Girl) - only ever answers/asks questions on one language (most likely Objective-C)

Comment: Nice! I like this one!

Comment: I like it too, but it would have to be actually measurable -- 30 consecutive answers to questions that all shared the same tag....

Comment: Not a behavior we want to encourage.

Comment: So this would be a badge that could potentially be taken away once you've received it?

Comment: @Joel: You don't want to encourage it?! But the MATLAB tag is my bread and butter, man! ;)

Comment: Ouch, that one's close to home! Come to think of it though, Java/C#/.NET posters would be just as likely to get the badge as we CocoaHeads. :-)

Comment: Yeah, I'd probably get this one for Java.

Answer (score 3):

**Scatter Gun** - more that 5 answers to the same question, each must have 2+ votes.

Comment: That would encourage spamming. :/

Comment: Spammers don't need encouraging, but it might encourage poor answers.

Comment: Spammers wouldn't get upvotes... there's no problem with this

Comment: Yes they won't get upvotes, but when they try to get the scatter gun badges, there will be spams created (no upvotes but still the spams existed)

Answer (score 3):

**Gleaner**: Answering two old (2+ months) unanswered questions *in a row*, with at least 1 upvote for each answer.

It's to catch the guys who systematically go through the old questions.

Comment: You'd need a "and they get <x> upvotes" - otherwise any old dirge would be posted to get badges.

Comment: Good point. See edit.

Answer (score 3):

**OCD** — Front page loaded more then 100 times a day

Comment: What about people who refresh the Newest Questions page more than 100 times a day?

Comment: What about people who check their profile for responses? (oops)

Answer (score 3):

**Welcome Back**

Awarded when someone returns after 30 days away from the site. It could be made "harder" by adding the condition that they post and have at least one upvote.

Would be a nice present to people returning and might encourage them to stick around this time.

Comment: So it's a reverse Enthusiast?

Comment: You could say that ;)

Comment: Here are some alternative names: **Off The Wagon**, **The 13th Step** (when an addict is now in control of their addiction: http://silkworth.net/magazine_newspaper/real_sep_1965.html)

Comment: **Unenthusiastic**

Comment: This would encourage people to not visit the site for 30 days which is lame, seems like this should just be a message rather than a badge.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline __Unthusiastic__!

Answer (score 3):

'Soul of Wit': getting many, many, votes for a very short answer.

Comment: I've found that most of my highly-voted answers are short. Then again, I have no experience with "many, many" votes.

Comment: Short and stupid seems a good formula for highly voted. Then it's tempting to add more explanation.

Comment: @Tom Hawtin - tackline that certainly worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

> **Specialist Badges - Bronze**
>   Lasted 15 days in the 30-day top 20 answerers list for a specific tag.

*Probably should require x number of questions posted in the same time frame to prevent gaining the badge on tags that only have a few posts.*

> **Survivalist**
>   Lasted 30 days in the 30-day top 20 answerers list for any tag.

They're the same badge, except if it were implemented as a specialist badge you could earn one per tag.  I wasn't sure if Jeff wanted bronze specialist badges however, so **Survivalist** is intended as an alternative.

Answer (score 3):

Voted 100 times on answers at least 5 months old.

Comment: Nice concept, but the name sounds like a form of voting that'd happen in Chicago.

Comment: Maybe name it [Mel Carnahan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mel_Carnahan) after the dead candidate who won a senate election.

Comment: Maybe call it Necrophiliac :)

Answer (score 3):

## Bouncer

Cast your first close vote.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to see a higher level of specialist badges.  Maybe even considered as a new badge level.  Platinum Specialist Badge.

Something like 10x the amount of votes needed as the gold specialist badge.

Comment: Or just as hard to obtain... the Jon Skeet badge.  One week has expired, and you answered the same question as Jon Skeet but YOU got more up votes.

Comment: The scary thing is that Jon would already qualify for this in C#

Comment: As for my other comment though, it would be an unattainable badge for Jon Skeet as surely he could never have more up votes than himself.

Comment: @Brian: isn't that a good thing - at last a badge that Jon Skeet won't be able to get? :)

Comment: Just because you can't imagine how I'd get more votes than myself doesn't mean it can't happen ;) (For one thing, I could post two answers :)

Comment: A friend of mine actually got an accepted answer to a question that Jon Skeet posted in. So it's not THAT big of a deal...

Comment: @a_m0d: the Tumbleweed badge? I'm guessing the average rep for Tumbleweed achievers is about 50...

Answer (score 2):

The Harry Enfield "You don't want to do THAT!" badge.

Awarded for an answer that tells the questioner they're doing it all wrong, without any constructive suggestion on how to do it right.

Comment: I'd go for this... if that answer gets lots of votes, and the poster marks it as accepted... BUT only if the answer does give some pointers as to what they should do.

Comment: One for the win32/usenet spambots ;-p

Comment: No way to tell this programmatically, is there?

Comment: Nearly every question regarding optimization would be a candidate for this badge.

Answer (score 2):

**XKCD** - a comment that gets someone to fix their answer: someone is *wrong* on stack overflow.

Comment: On an unrelated note, bobby-tables is a tag in stack overflow.

Comment: How would this be calculated?

Comment: If the answer is old, and a comment occurs, and the answer is changed soon afterwards, then it might be safe to assume it isn't coincidence.

Answer (score 2):

Gold badge that would be awarded for an answer that satisfies both `Necromancer` and `Enlightened` criteria, i.e.:

*First answer to a question more than 60 days later that was accepted with at least 10 votes.*

Not sure exactly what to call it, maybe **Enlightomancer**, **White Wizard** or even **Gandalf**.

This would be a good incentive for well researched answers to long-forgotten questions.

Comment: But as you would already get both the `Necromancer` and `Enlightened` badge (plus `Nice Answer` for good measure) do we really need another badge?

Comment: Do we really need any badges? I think it would be sufficiently rare and hard to get to merit gold, and it would encourage a good habit

Answer (score 2):

**Collaborator** -

The intent is to distinguish the editing of answers from providing supportive and helpful comments. Editor and Strunk&White, IIRC, can be attained simply by editing your own posts. In addition not everyone has the rep to edit other people's answers. ...just a thought that there should be a distinction.

For example: [SO question 2211388/serialize-object-to-xml-problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2211388/serialize-object-to-xml-problems)
I may know the answer, but there is an answer with a good start. Sure, I'll up-vote it (or at least I should). Then, instead of competing for the accepted answer, possibly duplicating most of the already up-voted answer and embellishing with some *campaign style* code snippets, I support the one already there.

I think this encouragement could produce higher quality answers. The downside to this, obviously, is how it could be implemented. I hope my explanation makes sense.

One possible implementation could be an icon only visible or click-able by the OP (?), or an additional option in the *flag* that tags the comment as supportive and collaborative.

Comment: so something that is awarded for has-edited-another-user's-answer-that-becomes-accepted?  because edits already count towards the Editor and Strunk&White badges.

Comment: No, that's not my intent - not everyone has the rep to edit other people answers. I was referring specifically to supporting comments as in examples, additional links. As far as Editor and Strunk&White are concerned, can't you can get these simply by editing your own questions and answers? There should be a difference.

Comment: ah, i see, that aspect isn't clear from your post.  i assumed you were talking about editing, which would be easy to detect (and anyone can edit a Community Wiki post, so it's not limited to high-rep users).  automatic detection of supportive comments is... well, not realistic... so this badge would have to be manually awarded.  to my knowledge, all the existing badges are awarded automatically.

Comment: I'll edit for clarity ;)

Comment: **Strunk** & White.  _Not Skunk_.

Comment: @SLaks: thanks...I can only guess I was really tired

Answer (score 2):

**Kitten-saver** Someone has asked a question and put their own answer on it within five minutes of asking. You come along with a better answer, and they accept yours rather than their own. Therefore you're preventing God from killing a kitten. Alternatively it could be awarded for preventing someone from [parsing HTML with regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246691/how-do-i-query-a-database-field-but-ignore-the-html-markup/2246713#2246713).

Comment: +1 for the "preventing someone from parsing HTML with regular expressions"

Answer (score 2):

## Monopolist

Received a golden tag badge for a particular tag while no one else has received a silver tag badge for particular tag yet. Or at least someting in those lines. It should award valuable contributors in "niche" tags who doesn't collect enough voteless answers to qualify for Unsung Hero and Tireless and like so.

Comment: I kind of like this, but at the same time I don't ever see it implemented.  It's one of those first come, first serve ideas that reward being the first prominent member on the site to be interested in a particular tag.  Anyone who joins after you gain the first silver can't get the badge even if you've lost interest.

Comment: @Andy: Fair point. The tag criteria should maybe be revised. Percentage of votes/answers/accepts as opposed to the amount of questions and the votes/answers/accepts others received in the particular tag during the period you were active?

Comment: A similar one: getting more than 500 points than anyone else for a particular tag in the last X month.

Answer (score 1):

**The Work Shy Fop Badge**

A bit like the Woot! badge, but only awarded if the site is visited more than once every working day (Mon - Fri) and never visited at weekends.

Skizz

Comment: How would you deal with timezone differences?

Comment: In Israel the work week is Sunday-Thursday. You'd think developers would be more aware of these things by now...

Comment: Won't work for people, like me, who never log out and always have a tab open in their browser for the site. How would you count the number of visits in this case?

Comment: @RobH: Probably the same way the Enthusiast and Fanatic badges do it.

Comment: @mmyers: Except that the Enthusiast and Fanatic badges only need 1 hit per day for them to count.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to see the 'Strunk & White' badge extended to reward those who edit and improve answers.  The difficulty is working out whether the editing is just for getting the badge, or whether it is genuinely improving the questions and answers.  (Clearly, editing your own entries wouldn't count.)

I'm not sure what to call it - Strunk & White sets a rather high standard to start out with.  And I'm not sure whether to make S&W a badge awarded multiple times - say on 100 edits, and then every 1000 after that, or whether to find a new name (Super Editor?  Vim or Emacs - at the recipients choice?  Nitpicker?) that is awarded every 1000 edits or so.

Answer (score 1):

**Coconuts from Mercia** — Asked a question with 10 or more up-votes that was then migrated to a different SOFU site.

Comment: After your last three suggestions, was expecting to see a fourth Jon Skeet-centric one.

Comment: You want more?  Not feeling the love?  Your screen name makes a better badge anyway :-)

Answer (score 1):

**Power Overwhelming** - Hitting rep cap X days in a row.

EDIT: Now with the epic and legendary badges, they are similar, but this one is for X consecutive days.

Answer (score 1):

**Full Deck** (bronze) - Awarded for getting all available bronze badges

**Full Deck** (silver) - Awarded for getting all available silver badges

**Full Deck** (gold) - Awarded for getting all available gold badges

Of course, with new badges getting added every so often this may be awkward to implement.

Comment: How can you get all bronze badges **if you don't have the `Full Deck` badge?!** We are programmers, for crying out loud!

Comment: It would have to be the non tag based badges (and not include the Silver Beta badge), otherwise the silver and gold ones would never be awarded.

Comment: Getting the full deck badge was based around getting all badges of that colour first. I have re-worded my question to remove any confusion

Comment: Earning badges for earning badges? I won't down-vote it but I'm not a fan.

Comment: There's a Silver badge for being in the beta, which no one can get anymore, meaning that the silver Full Deck would also be limited just to those in the beta.

Comment: You can't earn a bronze badge for getting all the bronze badges. If this were going to work logically, you would get a silver for earning all the bronze badges - which still doesn't really make sense. Aside from that, there is great effort to ensure that a badge cannot become un-earned. For instance, if you get a Full Deck (bronze) and then a new bronze badge is added, you haven't fulfilled the requirements to achieve the Full Deck (bronze). There is a hint of something in there I do like. But I can't quite put my finger on it...but it doesn't have anything to do with gaining another badge.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure the exact specifics of this mechanism, but I've seen/had happened to me before where an answer is accepted, then unaccepted, then *another* answer was accepted in its place.

I think there should be a badge for "stealing" acceptance in this manner.

Note that this "stealing" has nothing to do with plagiarism. It's about improving an accepted answer with another answer that's *even better*. Sometimes I suspect that if a question already has an accepted answer with a few votes, even if it can be improved upon, people don't bother (perhaps because they don't think it'd be as rewarding because they're "too late"). Having this badge would encourage people to always try to come up with the best answers possible, regardless of whether or not there's already a decent one accepted or not.

Comment: I like this. I think there should be a minimum amount of time that has to pass (between the previous acceptance and the current one) before it can be awarded, just in case the OP made an error or it's early in the question's life and there are many people still giving replies. There is an issue of gaming if these badges can't be revoked -- simply unaccept and accept a new answer every n days. But at the same time, I'm not sure limiting this badge to 1 awarding per question is a good idea, since we want to promote answer improvement. Hmmm...

Comment: This is close to the Populist badge. Or, if I rephrase, the Populist badge already encourages to post better answers even if there is already one accepted.

Answer (score 1):

[**Corrupt wisdom**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454): have an accepted answer with 10 upvotes featuring at least 42 combining characters.

Answer (score 1):

**Power Level** badge, for users with over 9,000 rep.

Answer (score -1):

**Slacking Off at Work**

For people who spend most of their workday on SO!

Comment: Or, even more appropriately, on Meta SO. :-)

Comment: **Meta.Slacker**

Answer (score -1):

**Revisionist** - Based on the ratio of posts to edits for the original author of a post. The higher the number of edits, the closer to the badge you get.

**Perfectionist** - Based on the ratio of posts to edits by anyone, including the original author. The lower the number of edits, the closer to the badge you get.

I don't know where the badge threshold would lie for these, but I think they would encourage better quality in posts.

Answer (score -1):

**We Understand You** - Provided a answer that was accepted when another answer had 10x votes.

Shows that you understood the question better than the majority of the community.

Comment: The top-voted answer had 10+ votes, or 10x the votes you got on your accepted answer?

Comment: Sounds like another version of `Populist`.

Comment: Usually when this happens, it is the higher-voted answer that is better, not the one that got the check mark.

Answer (score -1):

Almost equivalent to unsung hero (what it should have been maybe?)

> Bronze/Silver/Gold
>
> (Insert Name Here) - Number of
>   accepted answers doubles the number of
>   asked questions. With more then 10
>   accepted answers
>   (Insert Name Here) -
>   Number of accepted answers doubles the
>   number of asked questions. With more
>   then 25 accepted answers
>   (Insert Name
>   Here) - Number of accepted answers
>   doubles the number of asked questions.
>   With more then 50 accepted answers

Maybe instead of number accepted answers it could be doubles/triples/quadruples. This badge is more aimed at all the people who answer more questions then they ask.

EDIT: (A negative badge)

> Duper - First post closed because it
>   was a duplicate

Comment: Re Duper - We shouldn't have badges that reward negative behaviour.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with asking questions.

Answer (score -2):

Another one may be [Gives Credit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6930/new-badge-for-users-having-accepted-answers-for-all-the-questions-they-asked) (as [chaos suggested in his answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6930/new-badge-for-users-having-accepted-answers-for-all-the-questions-they-asked/6935#6935)) for users having accepted answers for all/most of the questions they asked.

Comment: Is that a 'Creditor' badge, then?

Answer (score -2):

**Googled**, for when N one's answers / one's questions appear as first in Google search results ;-)

*Just kiding*.  I think while it is a nice concept, it would be too hard to implement: first one would have to decide how to detect 'first result in Google search', and second decide what search query to use (whole question title?).

Comment: Use the server's referral logs to see people who've come in the first page of a google search?

Comment: When someone found your question via Google.

Comment: Too easy to game.  Google indexes SO very well, and it should be trivial to construct a long enough query to find any specific question.

Answer (score -2):

**Bridge**

Given to answers which are voted down because the answerer misread a word in the question.

The name comes from the Cream song "Badge," which was famously titled by mistake.

*The title has nothing to do with the song. Clapton saw Harrison's notes for this, and misread "Bridge" as "Badge." He thought this is what Harrison named the song, so they used it for the title.*

Comment: How would this be given? It can't be figured out manually.

Answer (score -2):

**Competitor** (Probably Silver)

After reaching 10K Rep, every 2 weeks there is a calculation taken of everyone else on the site with over 10K rep. Whoever has the most upvotes in the past 2 weeks gets this badge.

Anyone who won in one of the last 2 rounds is taken out of the running.

Comment: So Jon Skeet, Marc Gravell, and somebody else would alternate?

Answer (score -2):

**Cannibal** — deleted own accepted answer when other answers had more votes

**Edit**: based on bobobobo's observation, maybe **Seppuku** is a better term for it... or in Japanese: **切腹**

Comment: This sounds a bit like.. eating oneself actually.  autocannibal?

Comment: @bobobob... you are correct Sir!  Maybe "Seppuku" would be a better term.  We could even use the original Japanese: "切腹"

Comment: Unfortunately you can't actually delete an accepted answer - so the **Cannibal** badge is a non-starter.

Answer (score -2):

Has anyone suggested badge images yet, like the ones seen in Team Fortress 2 or on Kongregate?

(I haven't read all the suggestions above. Perhaps there should be a badge for 'failed to read all previous suggestions because of short attention span'?)

Answer (score -2):

**Charity**
A silver badge given when a user piggy backs on another user's question and offers a bounty to answer it. Resulting in an increase by 5 upvotes

**Philanthropy**
A gold badge given when a user piggy backs on another user's question and offers a bounty to answer it. Resulting in an increase by 15 upvotes

Answer (score -3):

A badge for anyone who asks or answers a question on the Trilogy on Christmas day

Comment: I think the "Has No Life" badge has already been proposed.

Comment: it's 2:20am on Boxing Day, and I managed to miss coming onto the site. YAY ! I must have a life.

Comment: @mmyers It's not on this thread.
@cometbill Christmas or Thanksgiving day.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102/additional-badge-ideas/46546#46546

Comment: Omg this is up tomorrow

Answer (score -3):

Similar to [Beginner's Luck](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102/additional-badge-ideas/999#999), **Rookie of the Year** (or "of the Week"). Hit 1000 rep within the first week of joining.

Comment: This will create many "What's your favorite..." being asked by newbies and quickly closed as duplicates.

Answer (score -3):

**Detox**: User with more than 200 reputation abstains from the web site for more than a week.

Comment: Why would you want people to **not** come to the website? =S

Comment: You have to both come to the web site, and later on not come to the web site. We don't want addicts, do we? (Don't answer that)

Comment: Surely SO is designed to create addicts?

Answer (score -3):

**Remorseful**

> Give a down vote to a user, and then give the same user an up vote within an hour (or similarly short period).

Basically a "well that's just *wrong*", followed by "but no hard feelings, ok?"

Comment: Interesting idea, but as the focus of SO (and all the other sites) should be the *post* not the *person* I'm not sure how this idea would sit with that.

Comment: They'd have to be to different questions / answers, right?

Comment: @Andrew - yeah, you take away rep from them for a bad post in one area, then give them some rep back for a good one somewhere else.

Answer (score -3):

## oops!

Vote your own question closed.

Comment: I couldn't come up with a one-worder :(

Comment: This would be easy to game just vote any of your real questions as NARQ, everyone will disagree with the close vote and it will disappear after a few days.

Comment: You need to be _able_ to close first, @Andy. That's a lot of rep. Also, it's not like there aren't [easily](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/3/editor) [gameable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/9/autobiographer) [badges](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/36/peer-pressure) [out](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/4/cleanup) [there](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/7/critic).

Comment: Excuse me, @Andrew, I'm not a native speaker, where's the profanity?

Comment: Urban dictionary: [whoopsie](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=whoopsie&defid=345062)

Comment: In my defense, Oops => whoops => whoopsie :( fixing

Answer (score -3):

**Professor**

User who's majority of rep (maybe 90% or so) is from up-votes on accepted answers. With a minimum rep of 10,000.

**Pupil**

User who's majority of rep (maybe 90% or so) is from questions. With a minimum rep of 10,000.

**Minority View**

User who commonly up-votes something that has very many down-votes or down-votes somthing with a lot of up-votes. (Basically disagrees with community)

**Poor Sport**

User who down-votes all competing answers to the same question as himself.

Thats all I can think of for now, I may add more later.

### Update

What about badges you have to be nominated for? Like..

**Above and Beyond**
Must be nominated by 20 users for going above and beyond to help them.

Comment: Negative badges aren't accepted, so "Poor Sport" won't be accepted. Mutually exclusive badges are also fairly unlikely.

Answer (score -4):

**Best of a Bad Bunch** - For every X answers where you're the highest voted (and at least 2 upvotes) but the answer isn't accepted. Acts as encouragement to give good answers to questions that are unlikely to ever satisfy the OP.

Comment: Anything like the Populist badge? http://stackoverflow.com/badges/37/populist

Answer (score -4):

**That's not my name**

Change your name from "Unknown (google)" within 5-10 minutes of registering on the site.

Comment: So those who register first don't ever get the badge?

Comment: No, as they're forced to enter their name as far as I know. This is to encourage the 1000s of "Unknown (google)"'s to reveal themselves. The alternative is to just give them a stupid random name

Comment: I'd want that badge, no fair

Answer (score -5):

**Underminer**, or **Zealot**

when you downvote more than (three?) competing answers on the same thread

Comment: We shouldn't really support such behavior with a badge.

Comment: @gnovice:  these badges, like "prison tattoo" are meant to deter this kind of behavior, not encourage

Comment: This is behaviour that should be showing up in the moderation tools, not being awarded a badge.

Comment: And then the mods can award the badge?

Answer (score -5):

***Anger Management***
Awarded for every 100 consecutive posts that don't result in a close of a flag.

Obviously, the criteria could be tweaked but this is intended to encourage people to write on-topic contributions that don't troll or incite others into angry responses.

Answer (score -5):

**Transcendent** — 100K rep, can be awarded multiple times, for each 100K rep.

Answer (score -5):

**Overlord** — Awarded for having the most rep.  This badge can be lost when you no longer have the most rep.  (could also be calls **The One Badge**.

Comment: I like. Sounds ..precious.. my precious..

Answer (score -5):

A **Hall of Fame badge** for those who will reach 100k reps.

Comment: Wow, these last four are pretty much all for Jon Skeet.

Comment: You could just go to page 1 of the Users tab for this.

Answer (score -5):

*Blowhard* for someone who posts in many different tags, but doesn't have any accepted answers... a failed generalist.

*Socrates/Know Thyself* for very large percentage of answers (100%) upvoted or accepted

*Badger* for someone who suggests a badge here that becomes real

Comment: Blowhard doesn't make sense because badges shouldn't be rendered invalid by subsequent (normal) actions.

Answer (score -7):

**Downer** or, **Parent**

Votes for closing of threads with high traffic

[for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3947/music-to-listen-to-while-coding-closed).  Stuff that comes out of these threads bring color to the site.

Answer (score -8):

**Snake** or **Pirate** for copy and pasting somebody elses previous answer into a new question without linking to it.

Comment: The checks for that would be wayyy to heavy.

Comment: Have community check? I know I usually fume at seeing such obvious plagiarism, even when not directed at me.

Comment: We should only give badges for *good* behaviour.

Comment: @Æther: Now that I have used these tools for a while I agree 100%

Answer (score -9):

**Deity** — name is Jon Skeet

Comment: It would be very confusing when everyone changed their display name to "Jon Skeet" (might be fun for April Fools' day though.)

Answer (score -13):

**Prison Tattoo** — For going into [penalty box](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/) more than once.

Comment: Encourages negative behaviour.

Comment: I don't think this is meant to encourage negative behavior. See discussion under rjstelling's "troll" badge http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102?sort=votes&page=1#answer-111

Comment: This would be better denoted on the user's profile page, in a stats window.