# Auto-Format/Auto-Insert MSDN Links for Keywords in Posts

Tags: feature-request, posts

This suggestion stems from the frequency with which I am inserting links to MSDN in my posts (especially the .NET/C#/LINQ related ones):

An option on each post which upon submission, tells the parser to automatically format any keyword that has an associated MSDN page, and is enclosed in backticks (`). This could apply to a number of languages, including C#, VB.NET, F#, C, C++, and others. A similar feature for linking Java keywords to the Sun documentation could also work. If differentiation between languages is needed, this can be done based on the tags.

If people aren't too keen on the idea of it being automated (though I don't see *much* scope for it to go wrong/be detrimental, providing that only the *first* instance of a keyword is processed), the Markdown parser could be slightly extended to utilise some lightweight syntax for adding links to language keywords.

Here's an example post (ignore the fact it doesn't make sense out of context):

**Unprocessed**

> In your method that takes an `IList<DateTime>`, I think you want to subtract subsequent `DateTime`s to give you the intervals between events. If you then `yield each resulting`TimeSpan`object along with the associated`struct`, that should give you the correct results.

**Processed**

> In your method that takes an [`IList<DateTime>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y536ey6.aspx), I think you want to subtract subsequent [`DateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx)s to give you the intervals between events. If you then [`yield`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx) each resulting [`TimeSpan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) object along with the associated [`struct`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ah19swz4.aspx), that should give you the correct results.

Edit: Erm, links aren't terribly easy to see on *meta*, so be sure to hover over.

As far as implementation goes, the MSDN links for the more common types/keywords within the .NET Framework (for example) could be cached, so the aditional load would be minimal, given that processing is only done when a post (question or answer) is made.

Of course, this is far from being the most important feature of editing, but I would imagine that it could be a significant timesaver, at least for the sizable number of us answers that refer to MSDN a lot! Any thoughts and/or further suggestions on this?

Comment: Partial dup: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1703/make-it-easier-to-link-to-documentation-for-common-technologies

Comment: Well, both address the same problem, but I prefer the solution proposed in #1703 to this one. The biggest advantage of MSDN linking is simply that the system could compensate for MSDN's habit of breaking links...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> tells the parser to automatically format any keyword that has an associated MSDN page, and is enclosed in backticks (`)

I *really* wouldn't want that; I tend to be pretty `strict` about using backticks for any `class` names etc, but I only add links to the **important** concepts in an answer; if everything in backticks (with a match) is a link, it is just noise and you can't find the bits that matter for that question. IMO.

To take your example as a case in point; I'm sure most of those don't vastly add to the answer. Unless the poster is asking how to represent a date, we should probably assume that either they know what a `DateTime` is (or at least, what a search engine is); no need to link it.

Comment: I agree. I want more control over how my post is formatted/linked. Automated linking would trivialize any *relevant* links I choose to include. I hate automated linking, in general (think Yahoo! mail). It's annoying and the poor link choices aren't usually relevant to the message.

Comment: Explicit control then, perhaps?

Comment: But I have that already... I explicitly link things I want to?