# Replace links with page titles when referring to most linked sources (MSDN, Wikipedia, ...)

Tags: discussion, feature-request, hyperlinks

Both *MSDN* and *Wikipedia* are very referenced documentation resources.

Would be possible to automatically replace not formated links, like:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions.aspx

with the page title:

[RegexOptions Enumeration (System.Text.RegularExpressions)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions.aspx)

or you're only implementing this on SE sites because all it requires is a database query instead of scraping the title?

I'm in doubts about if this is allowed in MSDN or Wikipedia, but that's not for evil purposes, totally the opposite.

I've seen many questions linking MSDN / Wikipedia without formatting the link, like:

- [How can I pass more than one enum to a method that receives only one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6022306/how-can-i-pass-more-than-one-enum-to-a-method-that-receives-only-one/6022334#6022334)
- [Lambda expression returns method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4931792/lambda-expression-returns-method/4931810#4931810)
- [Lambda expression returns method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4931792/lambda-expression-returns-method/4931831#4931831)
- [What are 1NF, 2NF and 3NF in database design?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/723998/can-someone-please-give-an-example-of-1nf-2nf-and-3nf-in-plain-english/724000#724000)
- [what is the difference between atan and atan2 in c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283406/what-is-the-difference-between-atan-and-atan2-in-c/283410#283410)
- [What does 'foo' really mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53609/what-does-foo-really-mean/53612#53612)

Of course, I'm refering to the post editor, and not about comments, because as Jeff said in [Replace links with the current question title in comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77394/replace-links-with-the-current-question-title-in-comments/86909#86909), comments are processed on the fly.

Comment: Can someone bake a SEDE query which would show us which external resources SO often links to?

Comment: Related, doing it in user scripts: [Including Documentation Links In Posts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83603/including-documentation-links-in-posts)

Answer (score 12):

I totally second this.

Manuals I would like to see benefit from this (in addition to MSDN and Wikipedia):

- The jQuery docs
- The mySQL docs
- [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference)

Comment: @Pekka I just included Wikipedia or MSDN, but as I said in the title, it is valid for **most linked sources**.

Comment: @Oscar I think there  will need to be a whitelist due to possible misuse. If they pick up on the suggestion, it might be worth suggesting reliable sources here

Comment: @Pekka Agreed! :)

Comment: I thought including links to any other SE post will already have the title replace the link URL as the anchor text automatically?

Comment: @YiJiang ah, you're right. I thought it was just for the current site

Comment: @Yi, @‍Pekka: On Meta.SO I have no trouble automagically linking to meta.tex.sx. Conversely, linking automagically from meta.tex.sx to Meta.SO does _not_ work (just tested).

Answer (score 5):

Ooh, ooh, w3schools!

<sub>Who says Meta isn't funny anymore?</sub>

Comment: You apparently said it, going by the sequence of characters present on your answer here.

Comment: It will be me but... I don't get the joke... :-s

Comment: @fretje There's a [backlash against w3schools](http://w3fools.com/) because it's very widely used but there are a few mistakes. I don't know, seems a useful resource to me still - no documentation's going to be perfect.

Comment: How about lmgtfy.com ?

Comment: @Rup: Jep, I know about the backlash... still don't get the joke though...

Comment: @fretje, based on some of the comments I've heard about w3schools (on and off SO), I think a minor riot would break out if the team made w3schools one of the "official documentation sources."

Answer (score 2):

Great idea.

There are many reference pages (not only listed), and it would be great to show just the header, instead of full link, which can be very long.

Some of the links I keep on seeing :
http://www.cplusplus.com
http://linux.die.net
http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/

Answer (score 2):

I like this idea, but I see an issue: there are lots and lots and lots of sites out there. You have your most commonly linked sites, I have mine. Ok, everyone will agree on Wikipedia. I don't think I've ever linked to MSDN, but I link to Ubuntu man pages almost every day. And to Debian, FreeBSD, OSX, etc, plus the POSIX specs and a couple others (guess [which site](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) I'm most active on). And on another site ([Science fiction and fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/)), I don't care about all them computer stuff, but I'd want [IMDB](http://imdb.com/) and [ISFDB](http://www.isfdb.com/).

The issue is, with so many sites involved, to cope with the sheer number of candidate sites.

On the plus side, there's a precedent: [chat oneboxing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57286/what-links-and-sites-are-handled-specially-in-chat).

Answer (score 2):

I totally agree! I miss this feature.

In general it should be easy to dynamically analyze which domains are most commonly linked and add them to auto-resolving list without human interaction. This way nobody has to neither maintain nor monitor frequently used resources. Because it is just a matter of downloading the page and reading `<title>` tag, most of the time the same code could effectively handle most of the sites.

When performance comes into play, there are several ways to tackle this: caching and scrapping in background so that the resolved title appears after some time.

P.S.: And I would add [JavaDoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/) to the mix...