# Double return within <sub> breaks markdown

Tags: support, markdown

On [Cognitive Science](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/) we expect answers to include a full list of references on which the answer was based at the bottom of the question. There are a few ways in which to format this list and we haven't decided on a preferred format yet.

One of the ideas is to wrap the list of references in `<sub>` tags as it [*"deemphasizes the reference section rather than emphasizing it"*](https://cogsci.meta.stackexchange.com/a/199/21).

This looks as follows:

<sub>Neher, A. (1991). Maslow's theory of motivation: A critique. Journal of Humanistic Psycholgoy, 31, 3. [FREE PDF](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/)

Mahmoud A. Wahba, Lawrence G. Bridwell, [Maslow reconsidered: A review of research on the need hierarchy theory](https://cogsci.meta.stackexchange.com/a/199/21) (1976), [or a free pdf scan here](http://larrybridwell.com/Maslo.pdf)</sub>

In order to place the second reference on a new line, two spaces need to be added at the end of the first reference. **Using <sub>(the more logical)</sub> return breaks markdown!** Adding a first return only adds a space. Everything after a second return isn't subscript anymore.

<sub>Neher, A. (1991). Maslow's theory of motivation: A critique. Journal of Humanistic Psycholgoy, 31, 3. [FREE PDF](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/)</sub>

Mahmoud A. Wahba, Lawrence G. Bridwell, [Maslow reconsidered: A review of research on the need hierarchy theory](https://cogsci.meta.stackexchange.com/a/199/21) (1976), [or a free pdf scan here](http://larrybridwell.com/Maslo.pdf)

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you separate the items using two line breaks, you cause each of them to be put in a separate `<p>` paragraph tag. According to the HTML standards the `<sub>` subscript tag is only allowed to be used *within* paragraphs of next, not surrounding them (though some browsers may support it). This is the same reason that you can't apply a link or bold/italic formatting to multiple paragraphs of text.

> [<sub>**Bold, subscript or linked,</sub>
>
> it won't work properly over multiple paragraphs!**](http://example.com/)

It would be possible for Stack Overflow's markdown parser to automatically generate `<sub>` subscript tags within each `<p>` paragraph tag of the output, but that would create different semantics for Markdown than for HTML and only be useful in uncommon situations like this.

I don't think that's likely to happen. I hope they eventually  [add explicit support for citing scientific literature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116397/add-explicit-support-for-citing-scientific-literature) and make hacky formatting like this unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I was also planning to look for/write a similar post as the one you linked to, you saved me some work there. ;p

Comment: Or, @Steven, what about [Markdown footnotes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5017/markdown-footnotes) instead?

Answer (score 0):

I seem to discovered a trick that saves time: See https://money.stackexchange.com/q/53806/10763.

Instead of surrounding each paragraph with `<sub>` and `</sub>`, it suffices only to place `<sub>` at the commencement of a paragraph as usual; but then place the same number of `</sub>` (adjacently) as the number of `<sub>` tags used, at the end of your entire post, to avoid the trouble of terminating each paragraph with `</sub>`.

Please advise of further ameliorations or tricks!

Comment: This is a very ugly hack that relies on some rather obscure behavior of the SE Markdown parser. Kudos for discovering it, but honestly, I wouldn't rely on it still working in the future, as the parser evolves.

Answer (score 0):

As Jeremy answered, it's not a bug, but there's an easy workaround:

I see no issues if you use `<br />` to separate the references (and that is valid HTML). With one line break:

<sub>Neher, A. (1991). Maslow's theory of motivation: A critique. Journal of Humanistic Psycholgoy, 31, 3. [FREE PDF]

Mahmoud A. Wahba, Lawrence G. Bridwell, [Maslow reconsidered: A review of research on the need hierarchy theory] (1976), or a free pdf scan</sub>

With two line breaks:

<sub>Neher, A. (1991). Maslow's theory of motivation: A critique. Journal of Humanistic Psycholgoy, 31, 3. [FREE PDF]


Mahmoud A. Wahba, Lawrence G. Bridwell, [Maslow reconsidered: A review of research on the need hierarchy theory] (1976), or a free pdf scan</sub>

[Link to answer in formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/266288/189029)