# Autocomplete/autoinsert links to API docs (or similar publically available docs)

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks

I usually find myself constantly linking to methods and properties in publically available docs for frameworks or libraries. I'd like to suggest an autocomplete feature when you enter a link in a special format to embed the link automatically to a relevant API doc.

Question tags can be used to help the autocomplete filter the results to keep them relevant.

#### Usecase Example 1: Linking to Java API doc on a Java tagged question

I'm answering a question on a java tagged question. So when I enter `api:toString` the editor should open up a context list and give suggestions such as [`Object.toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()).

#### Usecase Example 2: Referring to another API doc on a Java tagged question

I'm answering a question that is a java framework, .e.g. play. So when I enter `api::play:Play.version` it will give a suggestion to [`Play.version`](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/1.1/play/Play.html#version). The double colon is there to indicate that you are referring to another API doc (so it doesn't collide with the ones in the question's tags).

This could also be extended to suggest frameworks that are tied to a technology. E.g. in a question with the Java tag, typing in `api::p` would suggest frameworks that begin with the letter P that are tied to Java such as Play Framework, powermock, etc.

---

Obviously this will require scraping api docs, but they are most of the time formatted in the same way. Also there is the issue to select what API docs to support, but this could be limited at first. I'd think focus should be on .NET and Java or whatever is the popular technology or framework on stack exchange.

I think this would be a nice to have feature on stackoverflow (and other programming related stackexchange sites such as programmers and game development). But I can imagine that you don't need to just have links to api docs. On sites such as superuser, ubuntu or unix something such as `man:` would autosuggest inserting link to a man page.

Comment: Heavily related: [Make it easier to link to documentation for common technologies](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1703)

Comment: I feel somewhat compelled to hack this together myself since I very often add links to api docs.

Comment: @Spoike: If you want to hack this together yourself, you might be interested in [Stack Apps](http://stackapps.com/).

Comment: @CodyGray thanks for the tip, I'll look into it

Answer (score 3):

> **NOTE:** I had to take this script down due to terms of service violation, but the apps page is still there for anyone who wants to be inspired by it and work on their own solution.

I've made a Greasemonkey/Tampermonkey user-script that takes the following `api:[tagname]:[searchterm]` string, autocompletes using DuckDuckGo and converts it to a link to a api doc.

It is listed in Stack Apps here: [duckduckstack - The StackExchange API Doc Autocompleter](https://stackapps.com/q/3286/10294)