# Provide a way to quickly link to a question within MarkDown

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, markdown

From [Uservoice](https://web.archive.org/web/20090328235229/http://stackoverflow.uservoice.com:80/pages/general/suggestions/97836-provide-a-way-to-quickly-link-to-a-question-within-markdown):

> One of the nice features in FogBugz is
> the ability to type "case 17" in the
> body of a case, and have it
> automatically create a link to case #17.
>
> If it's possible to extend MarkDown,
> it'd be great to be able to simply
> type "#17" in the body of a question
> or comment and have it render as a
> link to question #17 on the site.
>
> It'd be even nicer if "#17" was
> automatically expanded to the full
> title of the question, linked to that
> question.
>
> This would be especially handy when
> reporting duplicates - you could
> simply type "duplicate of #1234" and
> have SO build the link for you.

I'd like to be able to link to SO/Meta questions from SF and vice versa via a small link.

Comment: This is somewhat related to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1010/advanced-syntax-ideas

Comment: Should also help when the title of a question was change AFTER then link as created.

Comment: When using bare URLs that link to the very same site, then this is implemented since 2010-11-05: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49433/replace-trilogy-raw-links-with-the-current-question-title/69483#69483

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Copy-pasting the whole URL is much easier for me because when I type out the link text I can then look to the URL to see what the question title is. It would actually be more trouble for me personally to bother with the ID's than it would be for the whole URL.

Comment: @TheTXI - Agreed. I *assumed* that the link, #17, would be expanded to the title *and link* of the question. I would add auto-expansion to the feature request; otherwise, it is *less useful* than just pasting the URL.

Comment: When using bare URLs that link to the very same site, then its current title is automatically inserted when the page is rendered, since 2010-11-05: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49433/replace-trilogy-raw-links-with-the-current-question-title/69483#69483

Answer (score 2):

When I saw the question title, I thought I would hate it. But I don't.

It might be nice to have user-friendly title-links instead of copy-pasted URLs (easily). As the Stack sites  becomes more complete with answers, they will tend to become **more self-referential**.

Although I am a bit dubious about how often I would look up, remember, and type in a 6- 7- 8- 9-digit number number, #941584, rather than just copy-and-pasting the whole shebang ([byte + byte = int... why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/941584/byte-byte-int-why)).

Answer (score 2):

When linking to [Question 12345] the question text should be displayed like "How do I change the oil in my car?" instead of just a question number.