# Interwiki links for the stackoverflow engine?

Tags: feature-request

Have you (Jeff, Joel and the other powers that be) thought about adding an interwiki link system to SO. What I mean is a shortcut notation to link to specific sited in the way you can configure [MediaWiki](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki).

Some suggestions:

```
[so:Great programming quotes] would link to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58640/great-programming-quotes
[su_kw:linux] would link to http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/linux
[wikipedia:Microsoft Access] would link to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Access
[bugzilla:mozilla: 499958] would link to https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=499958
[sourceforge:plane-disaster] would link to http://plane-disaster.sourceforge.net/
```

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4715/provide-a-way-to-quickly-link-to-a-question-within-markdown
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1010/advanced-syntax-ideas

Comment: Also related: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/147.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the thing though - in order to FIND bug 499958 on Mozilla, you need to be on that page anyway (except for a few edge cases) - so at that point it's *more* work to get just the bugid out of the link instead of copy/pasting the link.  The same goes for titles in SO, and most projects on sourceforge.

Tags on other SO-family sites and article names on Wikipedia could be linked without needing to reference their url, but those are edge cases.  How often to people link to those pages though?  And honestly I've already memorized http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/article-name

Comment: Its more work to get the bugid out of a bugzilla url. However, [bugzilla:mozilla: 499958] is much more readable than a bugzilla url.

Answer (score 1):

I would like this for linking to questions and tags across the SO trilogy, but I think the rest of it is overkill.

Comment: And the feature in that form is already planned.