# Display title of question rather than its URL when posting internal links in comments

Tags: feature-request, comments, auto-linking

Ok, this is a really simple one and will be well worth doing IMHO.

When you put a link in a comment you get something like this:

> Pretty similar (if not dupe) to
>   **stackoverflow.com/questions/410085/…**
>   – cletus 1 min ago

I'm proposing that when you post a link to the same site, instead of using an abridged URL, use the question text so the result would be:

> Pretty similar (if not dupe) to
>   [What reasons are there NOT to use OpenID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/410085/what-reasons-are-there-not-to-use-openid)
>   – cletus 1 min ago

which is much much more useful.

Comment: As a rule, I'm against telling other people that doing something with their software is simple unless I supply code. Other than that, I'm in total agreement w/ you re: the feature.

Comment: I normally have to be very confident to say something (in someone else's code) is simple but I can't see how this isn't. SO is already parsing the comment looking for URLs. The URL will have a distinct pattern such that you can figure out the site easily enough. And the question ID is in the URL so it's just a lookup for the title.

Comment: Related: [Userscript to auto-replace SOFU links in comments?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/89378)

Comment: We [shouldn't put tags in titles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/171231).

Comment: How question asked in 2009 be a duplicate of a question raised in 2011? . In particular, Jeff's answer  to related question doesn't make sense, as based on current implementation and not considered possible changes to implement requested behavior.

Comment: @MichaelFreidgeim The date on the question matters far less than the answers. The official reply for the moment is still "the current implementation prevents us from doing this and at the moment we aren't considering changing that implementation".

Comment: @AnnaLear, in this case you need to change (at least for this question) the standard response"This question has been asked before and already has an answer", because this question was asked earlier and also has answers(but not the official reply)

Answer (score 13):

Would be nice to have this for internal links in normal posts as well - while it's not *too* much extra effort to copy the title in and link that instead of just pasting the URL, it's still extra effort, and some don't bother with it.

#### See also: [Provide a way to quickly link to a question within MarkDown](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4715/provide-a-way-to-quickly-link-to-a-question-within-markdown)

Comment: Yeah I've seen that but IMHO it's overly complicated (and different to this anyway). I'm of the opinion that "internal" URLs should always display the question text instead of the URL and it should be relatively easy to implement that.

Comment: I still want the option to choose what is displayed for a internal link, as sometimes the quesion title is to long to format well in my answer.   However default to the quesion title would be greate.

Comment: It’s worth noting that on mobile it’s a lot more effort to do it properly. Usually I copy the URL, write comment, paste bare URL, post comment, follow link to question, select and copy title, go back to previous page, edit comment to insert title (which requires precise cursor positioning)

Answer (score 2):

I'd like it too, so just for reference: as comments are rendered on the fly (unlike regular posts, for which the HTML is [pre-cooked when saving](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95821/markdownsharp-not-a-complete-rip-from-stack-overflow/95838#95838)), Jeff once said [it's not likely to happen](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77394/replace-links-with-the-current-question-title-in-comments/86909#86909).

Even more, even `<...>` notation was [rejected for that same reason](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56605/recognize-urls-in-angle-brackets-in-comments/62877#62877).

Comment: Why do not create a background process to add url titles to saved Comments?