# What do icons on the tags mean?

Tags: support, faq, tags, advertising, sponsored-tags

What does an icon on the tag mean, for example the "rg" before the sql-server tag as pictured below?

[image]

[Return to FAQ index](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/)

Answer (score 142, accepted):

This is a sponsored tag — in other words, a company has decided to pay money to put an icon and to put links on the tag page. Moderators cannot edit these; they are only added as a result of a tag sponsorship.

The tag sponsorship program is currently active on Stack Overflow only.

As for the tag in the question, the tag was sponsored by Red Gate, whose logo is shown as part of the tag in your screenshot.

Note that [as of Sept. 1, 2011](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33081/should-tags-that-represent-concepts-be-sponsorable/104757#104757), Stack Exchange no longer allows branding like this to be purchased for tags that represent generic concepts or are otherwise not *strongly* associated with the company purchasing them.

A tag that retains this branding is [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) — click through to see what this form of sponsorship entails.

Comment: How come Jetty, google-maps-api-3 still have icons next to tag.

Comment: Jetty appears to be sponsored by Webtide. Webtide created and maintains jetty, so this would fit the "strongly associated with the company purchasing them".

Comment: And how to sponsor a tag?

Comment: @MoslemBenDhaou email ads@stackexchange.com with details and they will get back to you. (See [here](http://stackexchange.com/mediakit))

Comment: Google Cloud Platform tag in ServerFault SE seems to have an icon.     https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud-platform

Comment: It may be worth updating this answer to mention [Collectives on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives). (Also, I think the [android] example may no longer be true, judging from the lack of icon next to the tag now.)