# What does "rg" on the performance and sql-server tags mean?

Tags: support, tags, advertising, sponsored-tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does rg mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30187/what-does-rg-mean)

What does "rg" on the `[performance]` and `[sql-server]` tags mean?

Comment: give me the answer and close if you wish. strange people...

Comment: This kind of question belongs on meta.stackoverflow.com

Comment: Duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30187/what-does-rg-mean

Comment: Oh man, talk about a superball :)

Answer (score 3):

These tags seem to be sponsored by RedGate.
Click on the tag to see references to the sponsor.

Comment: IMHO it's a shame..