# What is the little "bird" icon on the testing and unit-testing tags for?

Tags: support, tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do icons on the tags mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30187/what-do-icons-on-the-tags-mean)

What is the little "bird" icon on the testing and unit-testing tags for?  (easy question I hope)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you [click on one of the tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/testing), you can see that they are sponsored by Telerik:

> http://sstatic.net/so/img/tag-logo-telerik.png
>
> **Sponsored links for this tag**
>
> - [Telerik automated testing tools](http://ads.stackoverflow.com/a.aspx?ZoneID=0&BannerID=1748&AdvertiserID=188&CampaignID=1015&Task=Click&SiteID=1&RandomNumber=859163)
> - [A Visual Studio plug-in for automated testing – see short video](http://ads.stackoverflow.com/a.aspx?ZoneID=0&BannerID=1749&AdvertiserID=188&CampaignID=1016&Task=Click&SiteID=1&RandomNumber=337668)
> - [A standalone automated testing tool – see short video](http://ads.stackoverflow.com/a.aspx?ZoneID=0&BannerID=1750&AdvertiserID=188&CampaignID=1017&Task=Click&SiteID=1&RandomNumber=476691)

Comment: +1 - That's the beauty of ads on SO. Even though I'd probably never use it, buy it or even talk about it, I'd click on the ad and hope to dig for screen shots just so I can see how they implemented the user experience. Then maybe I may talk about it, if just for that reason.

Comment: Heh I'm just glad it's not an ugly icon ;)