# The PHP tag needs a tag icon

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow

The icons added to tags make clear which tags a question belongs to. I see that icons have now been added to [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23), [asp.net](/questions/tagged/asp.net), etc. Can we have an icon for [php](/questions/tagged/php), please?

Comment: Then I hope someone comes up with sponsorship for php tag...

Comment: Technically, you could sponsor it... then you'd get to choose whatever icon you wanted.

Comment: I came over to meta just to suggest this. I'm actually flabbergasted that those icons are "sponsored" icons or whatever. That seems just... weird to me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Tags with icons are sponsored. The sponsor also provides links on the tag page.

The PHP tag will only get an icon if someone sponsors the tag, and even then it's not guaranteed or likely to be the official PHP icon/logo.

Gratuitous FAQ Link: [What do icons on the tags mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30187/what-do-icons-on-the-tags-mean)

Comment: thanks buddy, did not know that :)

Comment: the `c#` tag no longer has an icon as of today

Comment: And for quite some time already @sla