# Why does the SO C# tag show a "D" icon on it?

Tags: discussion, tags, sponsored-tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do icons on the tags mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30187/what-do-icons-on-the-tags-mean)

Shouldn't it be 'C#'?  Who decides what icon to use?  Who put it there?  And the big one, why is it a 'D'?

Comment: Sponsoring by *D*evExpress

Comment: Should be on meta.

Comment: Recommend we move this to meta

Comment: Tag sponsors should reconsider the value of their investment. I'd like to have a more significant set of data, but I am a bit pissed off by these icons. C# is C#, not an ugly D followed by C#.

Answer (score 1):

Try clicking on it. You'll see a big obvious advert with that logo in it at the top of the page.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that ***[DevExpress](http://www.devexpress.com/)* is now involved in the tag sponsorship program**. Hence, a "D" is displayed.