# Tags and logos in Stack Overflow

Tags: support, tags, sponsored-tags

I noticed that Adobe-related, .NET-related and Android-related products tag names have a nice and neat logo attached. I like it because it makes visual filtering easier (even though the "interesting tags" and "ignored tags" are great features, they can't cover it all - most people are, like myself, lazy, and don't want to put every single tag they could in those lists).

To my knowledge, C or C++, for instance, do not have a logo (though one could wonder why), so it's normal that the tag would not have one attached to it. But Java does have a logo, doesn't it? The little coffee cup? My question: why isn't that logo in the "Java" and other Java-related tags?

(All right, this question is not really a big big problem, but it's been bugging me and I just want to know why things are the way they are :)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The images on certain tags are because a company has paid to sponsor the tag.  The logos aren't there to help filtering.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know at all... perhaps this should be put in the FAQ or someplace where you can easily spot it.

Comment: @Raveline - They are already part of the FAQ. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30187/what-do-icons-on-the-tags-mean

Comment: Oh... right, I missed it, my bad. Thanks again.