# Add the R logo to the R tag?

Tags: feature-request, tags, sponsored-tags

Hi,

I've noticed some tags bear a logo. It would be nice to have the R logo on the tag as well. Is this doable / legal?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tags have logos if they've been sponsored by companies (see the [faq entry](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30187/what-do-icons-on-the-tags-mean)). If you want to pay them to add a particular logo you can (see [Ad Sales and Sponsorships](https://stackoverflow.com/about/contact)), but I doubt they'll do it for free since it's one of the ways SO makes money

Comment: Thx, I wasn't aware of that.

Answer (score 2):

Logos on tags mean that they're sponsored tags.  Shoot some cash over to the team and I'm sure they'll be happy to put the logo on.

Comment: You don't even have to use the R logo! You can sponsor the R tag as a front for your own company. Though this has been known to produce a lot of... conflict, if your company is only tangentially related to the tag's concept.

Comment: @Grace: squatting FTW!