# Free logo on tags of open-source developments until they're filled by paid logos?

Tags: feature-request, tags, advertising, logo

This is a follow up of [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65180/add-the-r-logo-to-the-r-tag) after I found out that there is [free vote-based advertising for Open Source projects](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23899/proposal-free-vote-based-advertising-for-open-source-projects).

I was told that logos could be added to tags whenever somebody paid for it. Now I don't see that very likely to happen for big open-source projects like R. I do understand that SO need some income, but I guess that those logos on tags aren't the biggest income as yet.

Therefor I'd like to propose to add the logos to the tags of open source projects like R, at least until some company decides to pay to add their own logo.

Comment: Related: [What about Tag images for OpenSource projects?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/85511)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this could potentially damage sponsorships on tags.  The whole point of adding the icon to a sponsored tag is that it increases visibility and prompts users to investigate the tag.  The ideal situation for the sponsor is:

> User: *"Hey, why does that tag have a picture?" (click)*
>   User: *"Oh, there's some information about a company that specializes in this field and there's a link to the homepage" (click)*

If all tags that could have logos had them, then nobody would click on the sponsored ones to find out why.

Comment: Apparently, I'm not a marketing guy... I was hoping there would be something like "The Greater Good" in promoting valuable freeware projects, but that's not how the world turns around I guess.

Comment: @Joris: The tag wiki pages are probably sufficient enough - they'll contain a link to the project homepage in most situations.

Comment: it didn't really yet for the r-tag, but as I moved above 2000 reputation, that is solved by now. Thx for the tip.