# What about Tag images for OpenSource projects?

Tags: feature-request, sponsored-tags, open-source, open-source-advertising

I know that the ability to put an image on a tag is one way that SO does advertising, but what about open source projects that don't have a commercial sponsor?  Would it be possible to allow images to be placed on tags for open-source projects?

For example the Ruby language is open-source, and it has a nice little logo (a ruby, [image: Ruby logo]) that would look rather nice on the [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby) tag for related questions. Is this something that could be allowed, or are you reserving this as a special perk available only for advertisers?

Comment: A nice idea, but it would probably dimish the perceived value of the tag icon among those who pay for it... But it *would* be nice to have, no doubt

Comment: There's nothing stopping the Ruby community from chipping in enough money to buy a logo for their tag.

Comment: @canspice, any idea what "enough money" constitutes?  I tried clicking on the advertiser info link, but pretty much there's no kind of price schedule or for that matter any kind of pricing info there.

Comment: I think it's pretty clear that for that information you need to actually email them. "To buy ads or inquire about tag sponsorships, please contact us at ads@stackoverflow.com, or call 646-826-3868 to reach our ad sales team."

Comment: Related: [Free logo on tags of open-source developments until they're filled by paid logos?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/65916)

Answer (score 4):

I think this is a good idea. In the real world, advertisers and others often treat non-profits differently from commerical entities. It doesn't do any harm to anyone, and helps give visibility to open source projects. In fact, Stack Overflow already follows this logic with [free advertising for open source projects](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23899/free-vote-based-advertising-for-open-source-projects). Why not do the same here?

Comment: Thanks for the vote of confidence (and the edits)..    being somewhat new to meta, I'm not sure if I should now tag your response as the 'right answer' since I happen to agree with it, or wait a while to see if it (and/or my question) garner further up-votes or what?

Comment: @Chuck van der Linden - Meta doesn't really work the same way as the other sites. I personally feel that accepting answers on Meta is largely purposeless. To be blunt; on Meta, the fact you are the OP does not make your opinion any more special than anyone else. Answering as I've done is more about providing additional backing for your argument. If readers agree, they'll vote up; if not, they'll vote down. Ideally someone will feel strongly enough to make a counter argument. As long as there's engagement, we all get something out of it. :) So tick if you like - it makes no odds to me.

Comment: Also, for the avoidance of doubt - I think Meta reputation is pretty useless. Lots of Meta rep just shows you've got a big mouth, hang around here a lot, and like to argue. Yes, I've got quite a lot of Meta rep. ;)