# Why do some tags on Stack Overflow have associated images?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, sponsored-tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do icons on the tags mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30187/what-do-icons-on-the-tags-mean)

Why do some tags on Stack Overflow have associated images? Are they being promoted by sponsors? For example, why does `[silverlight]` display the [telerik](http://www.telerik.com/) logo?

[image]

Comment: They are in fact sponsored tags - you can read up more about them in [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30187/what-do-icons-on-the-tags-mean).

Comment: You forgot to circle six more.

Comment: @BalusC, I just wanted to show some examples...

Comment: @Grace, you're right but I looked for it before I asked the question and even when I wrote the title that question was not suggested... It is OK to be closed though