# What do images on tags indicate?

Tags: discussion, tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do icons on the tags mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30187/what-do-icons-on-the-tags-mean)

There are few tags in SO which have images embedded into it.

[image]

There are lot others which do not have any images on them.

[image]

So I was wondering if there is any significance of these images on tags? If yes, then what do they indicate? If there is no significance, then why do we have images on only few tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are sponsored tags. Companies pay SO some money to add an image to the tag for advertising purposes.