# Are SE moderators able to set an icon for a tag?

Tags: support, tags, advertising, moderator-abilities

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do icons on the tags mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30187/what-do-icons-on-the-tags-mean)

There are some tags on Stack Overflow that are shown with an icon, as it happens with [android](/questions/tagged/android). Is there an option that allows SE moderators to set icons for the tags?

Comment: See [What do icons on the tags mean?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30187/what-do-icons-on-the-tags-mean)

Comment: If I could, I'd be banned for the icon I'd put on [android].

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They are not. That's because tag icons are an advertisement option.