# Tag logos - A good idea?

Tags: discussion, tags, logo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do icons on the tags mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30187/what-do-icons-on-the-tags-mean)

Android has a logo, IOS doesn't.

Are tag logos even a good idea, seeing as the low number of logos?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The logos that you do see are there because someone (normally the company behind the technology) sponsored them.

iOS doesn't have a logo because Apple didn't sponsor a logo. Android does because (I assume) Google did.

Having a large number of tag logos would in my opinion be a bad thing - it would clutter the UI and distract from the actual tags and questions.

Having a low number does draw attention to those specific questions - precisely what they are designed to do.