# Logos on Flash related tags removed?

Tags: support, tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do icons on the tags mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30187/what-do-icons-on-the-tags-mean)

I noticed this morning that the Flash related tags like [flash](/questions/tagged/flash)  and [actionscript-3](/questions/tagged/actionscript-3) are no longer sporting the Adobe logo.  Is this by design?  I can still see logos for other tags, such as [android](/questions/tagged/android) and [facebook](/questions/tagged/facebook).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The logos appear only on *sponsored* tags.

Looks like Adobe no longer sponsor the [flash](/questions/tagged/flash) and [actionscript-3](/questions/tagged/actionscript-3) tags.

It is possible that the sponsoring period expired and they simply did not renew it (either by mistake or intentionally).

Comment: Adobe drops mobile flash development, now its not sponsoring the tag... hmmm...

Comment: @ಠ_ಠWon't - Strange coincidence, eh?