# Why does the google-app-engine tag on StackOverflow have an icon?

Tags: discussion, android, google, tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do icons on the tags mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30187/what-do-icons-on-the-tags-mean)

When I look under my tags it's the only one with an icon. Is Google 'funding' this? Maybe an attempt to make good with developers after the new pricing fiasco? The conspiracy theorist in me is curious.

Comment: The plot thickens! I just saw that the android tag also has an icon.

Comment: And android too, but oh yeah, it's owned by whats-their-name as well... :)

Comment: So then the answer is Yes, Google is 'funding' this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that this has been around since long before the pricing changes. Google has been one of the companies to sponsor several tags, along with Facebook and others. This lets them include official links on top of the tag wiki page, as well as drawing attention to their technologies. No real conspiracies required.