# Add tag icon from "windows-mobile" tag to "windows-phone"

Tags: feature-request, tags, windows-phone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do icons on the tags mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30187/what-do-icons-on-the-tags-mean)

Currently, when anyone uses a question tag "windows-mobile" a red Windows Phone apears appears next to the tag text.

Shouldn't the icon be moved to windows-phone tag instead?

P.S. Someone has done this a few minutes after the question was originally submitted. I am not after the credit, but at least one should have commented here about doing a change. This way a feature request would be "answered"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those icons are put there because a company is sponsoring the tag. In this case, the company sponsoring [windows-mobile](/questions/tagged/windows-mobile) has not decided to sponsor [windows-phone](/questions/tagged/windows-phone).

That raises the question though: perhaps they should be synonyms?

Except, now the company *is* sponsoring both tags, so it's all moot.

Comment: I thought icons were being added by high-rep users in tag wiki. Since it is sponsors who does it, everything seems clear now. Also windows-mobile, windows-phone, should be synonyms of windows-phone-7.1., windows-phone-7.5.

Comment: Probably not many people are going to see your retag suggestion here, @MaximV.Pavlov; if you feel strongly about it, you should post a separate feature request.

Comment: The person who silently added icon to windows-phone-7.5 as noted in my initial question's P.S. section, also made tags in my comment synonyms, so it is all done now. It is almost as we are being watched =)