# Why does in SO google chrome tag has its logo image but Internet explorer does not?

Tags: discussion, sponsored-tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do icons on the tags mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30187/what-do-icons-on-the-tags-mean)

I have just checked tags and saw that google chrome tag has its logo but there is no logo for internet explorer ? Is there any kind of favoritism here ?

Comment: Going to meta...

Comment: See [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30187/what-do-icons-on-the-tags-mean) for an introduction to sponsored tags - basically chrome has sponsored the tag whereas internet explorer hasn't bothered :-)