# Why do some tags in StackOverflow have icons, but the most don't?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do icons on the tags mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30187/what-do-icons-on-the-tags-mean)

Just out of curiosity!

For example, `Android` tag has an icon, but `iPhone` don't.

Who added those icons and how?

Comment: Please hold while you listen to some messages from our sponsors.

Comment: @MartijnPieters ooooh, I see what you did, there!