# How can we improve the situation for the GWT tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

The GWT tag has some rather unique properties:

- It's related to the top-level tag [java](/questions/tagged/java)
- It is often (correctly) tagged as [java](/questions/tagged/java) in addition to [gwt](/questions/tagged/gwt), because the question/answer may include java code and touch on Java technologies (GWT has Java syntax, plus it can be used together with actual Java on an Application server.)
- [java](/questions/tagged/java) answers to [gwt](/questions/tagged/gwt) questions usually don't fit at all (e.g. Java Swing solutions to handle a mouse click)

As [java](/questions/tagged/java) is automatically listed as the first tag, people often overlook the [gwt](/questions/tagged/gwt) tag, and answer the questions as if the tag wasn't there. This often happens even when people mention GWT in the question. (It's natural to assume that it's just another Java library, while in reality it's a separate runtime environment with Java emulation.)

Of course it's possible to deal with that by down-voting (or deleting, ...) such answers, but some problems remain:

1. Questions may look as if they have already been answered.
2. There are lots of users in the [java](/questions/tagged/java) tag (much more than in [gwt](/questions/tagged/gwt)), so these answers are frequent.
3. I dare to extrapolate from that data that similar things happen for misplaced up/down-votes, close votes, etc.

Can something be done to make it more visible that a question is specific to GWT (e.g. move the tag into first place)?

Are there any other tags in the same situation, so that we could find a common solution for this "class" of tags?

Comment: [tag:java-me] has a touch of this, too. Mind you, [quite a limited subset of ancient Java 1.3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CLDC#Noteworthy_limitations) is often not what Java SE 1.5+ developers normally expect. It's much less active though so occasional removal of java tag along with downvoting / commenting misguided answers rather [works for me](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13006300/j2me-thread-programming/13009875#comment17657177_13009875 "an example")

Comment: @gnat: But actually, the java tag is often correct, because in GWT, some things can be solved on the server side, where you actually have Java, ... It's the mix between Java, GWT and JavaScript that makes the [java] tag correct on the one hand, but the [gwt] tag is more important for these questions.

Comment: agree, for GWT this can be quite tricky (I dealt with it in one of the past projects). Heavier activity in this tag compared to java me also makes it harder to maintain - at the very least I would expect more (much more) reputation to spend downvoting wrong answers than in java me - and much more time spent on explanatory comments

Answer (score 4):

A Downvote with a comment seems sufficient.

The reverse often happens when an OP asks a [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) questions, and gets 6 answers, 5 of them are [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery). Or worse, an OP asks for a [css3](/questions/tagged/css3) animation question, and gets [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) answers.

If an answer does not meet the requirements of the question, it's not useful. If it's not useful, it should be downvoted.

I usually downvote the answer, leave a constructive comment, and provide a good answer of my own.

---

As for adding an image for the tag, that's done by **[Sponsoring the tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/30187/166899)**

Comment: However, while I can (and do) leave comments to such anwers, I can't leave a comment to a misplaced question up-/downvote/close vote, and any other actions besides wrong answers/comments.

Comment: @ChrisLercher: Why not? a misplaced question can be edited, if it cannot be salvaged via editing, it can be downvoted and/or closed.

Comment: I meant a "misplaced up-/down-/close vote on a question", not a "misplaced question"

Comment: @ChrisLercher: Oh, my bad. If you think the question's votes were wrong, there are several things you can do. Edit it, to make it better. Vote on it based on what you feel is right. Join a chat channel and bring the question to the awareness of other users.

Comment: While all of this is certainly possible (and good ideas), wouldn't it be even better to avoid the confusion in the first place (instead of dealing with this effect every time again)?

Comment: @ChrisLercher: How would you determine which tags are "critical" to be first? No, this isn't a viable solution in my eyes. I say do your duty as a community member, and if the question requires extra intervention, flag it for a mod, or bring it up in chat, where more experienced users generally hang out.

Comment: I don't know, if making [gwt] first is really a good solution. It's just the first idea. There must already be some mechanism in place to determine, which tags are first. Maybe a wild idea: There could be a contract between the java and gwt tag maintainers: "gwt tag asks the java tag if it may be first. java tag accepts/declines" This is really just a random idea, I don't have the solution. But it's hard to "counter" the overwhelming number of java users, and it's inefficient.