# How do I put an image in a SO tag?

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do icons on the tags mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30187/what-do-icons-on-the-tags-mean)

I've seen tags like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/youtube-api), that contains an image. When I try to edit a tag the tag image doesn't appear, it isn't editable. So how to put an image inside it?

Comment: These are sponsored tags. I am pretty sure they are paid for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to sponsor the tag if you want an image on it.

I don't know the specifics, but sponsoring means paying Stack Exchange.

See [this page](https://stackexchange.com/about/contact) for who to contact and how.