# SO tags while adding questions

Tags: discussion

Why does [paypal](/questions/tagged/paypal) on Stack Overflow have an icon, when as no other company-related tag seems to have it?
Is it based on any criteria?
Have you noticed other tags having icons on them?

Comment: It is a "sponsored tag."  I'm looking for the Meta post right now that describes them.

Comment: Here it is: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30187/what-do-icons-on-the-tags-mean

Answer (score 1):

It's a "sponsored tag".  The company payed SO to add that icon to their tag.  There are other tags that are sponsored, but obviously not *all* tags are sponsored.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook) [are](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-chrome) [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-maps).

Comment: Anyone know if there is a canonical list of sponsored tags?