# Could the Python tag use/have the Python Icon?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, tags

Some of the Tags on StackOverflow have little icons near them. What about the Python tag?

I really don't have much else to add to this post, it seems pretty summed up in that first sentence, but here is a short motivational speech on the matter:

Not all tags need an icon, I understand that. Some tags do have them - usually the larger tags, like Facebook. I believe that Python **deserves** to get an Icon, it is a *relatively* large part of the StackOverflow content, and has a very active community (especially in the [Python Chat Channel](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python)).

Comment: See: [What do icons on the tags mean?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/30187)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Icons are allowed on *sponsored* tags. To sponsor a tag, you must contact Stack Exchange.

```
To buy ads or inquire about tag sponsorships, please contact us at ads@stackexchange.com [...].
```

Source: https://stackexchange.com/about/contact

In short, it costs money to sponsor a tag and that's the only way to apply an icon to it.

Answer (score 5):

This has nothing to do with tags, but rather whether a tag is sponsored by a company/organization behind the technology. That's why [google-app-engine](/questions/tagged/google-app-engine) and [facebook](/questions/tagged/facebook) have icons, while a huge tag like [c](/questions/tagged/c) doesn't.

Note: The only companies who seem to buy sponsored tags are those for whom SO is the official developer forum. That's why, say, [java](/questions/tagged/java) isn't sponsored.

Comment: Whilst I think sponsored tags are fine, I hope that any/all tags never get considered for it personally. Tags are tags, not brand-signage.

Comment: @nickhar: True, but if it can make SE Inc. some money to keep the lights on for such a small annoyance, I'm good with it.

Comment: @Linuxious Yes, agreed. Just had a 'vegas-style' mental picture of SO under heavy sponsorship...

Comment: @nickhar: Um... ;)