# Can you add dart logo to all dart-related tags?

Tags: feature-request, sponsored-tags

The logo should apply to all: [dartlang](/questions/tagged/dartlang), [dart](/questions/tagged/dart), [dartium](/questions/tagged/dartium) (chrome with integrated) [dartvm](/questions/tagged/dartvm).

Comment: See [What do icons on the tags mean?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/30187/187824)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are talking about having these as [sponsored tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30187/what-do-icons-on-the-tags-mean), then someone will need to sponsor those tags before they get a logo.

Comment: Thx, Will ask some dart guys about it.

Comment: Thx for info. I guess it really doesn't matter so much. I though that those icons are just for users to add more visual recognition. I didn't know they are a part of ad campaigns.

Comment: @orian - Well, if a company/project want to get more attention on [SO] , they pay to sponsor a tag (or tags).