# Why does the VS2012 tag have the Windows 8 icon?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

I don't understand why the Visual Studio 2012 Stack Overflow tag, [visual-studio-2012](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2012), has the Windows 8 icon:

[image]

instead of the Visual Studio 2012 icon:

[image]

Comment: It's a sponsored tag.

Comment: Microsoft apparently chose to use that icon when they decided to sponsor the tag. It does seem like a weird choice... although slapping Windows branding on everything indiscriminately is something Microsoft is known to do.

Comment: See also: [What do icons on the tags mean?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/30187)

Comment: See also Mozilla being weird: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204433/who-stole-the-fox

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's actually sponsored with the Windows Azure logo, not the Windows 8 logo. The sponsored links for VS2012 are also all Azure links. Seems like Microsoft has chosen to sponsor the tag to promote the Windows Azure platform to VS2012 developers.

Here's the page for [visual-studio-2012](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2012):

[image]

Comment: This is correct. The Azure brand is sponsoring the Visual-Studio-2012 tag and features the Azure logo, not Windows 8.