# Does obscurity of a language/API indicate advertisement?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, advertising

**Does the obscurity of a language or system effect the legitimacy of a question about it, and if so, how much?  Is there a threshold by which a question could be considered acceptable or spam based on the popularity of the product?**

There are a number of languages out there, from the most popular of programming languages to the most unknown of one-man-made APIs.  While asking questions on SO about opinions on which is "better" or "they would use" is not acceptable, instead asking about facts regarding their functionality in order to make a judgement on viability for one's self very much is.  The issue is one of advertisement, which is not allowed on SO.

It seems possible that questions regarding obscure systems are more likely to be indicative of an intent to be seeking advertisement than systems than more popular ones.  If one were to ask a question about something that only 3 people in the world would know, it may be a sign that one is attempting to attract attention to the subject rather than get legitimate answers on it.  However, it also seems unfair to make such judgement as well.  Should a legitimate question about Bob's Foobarblarg Scripting Language really be considered less legitimate than, say, a Sun's Java one?  Both are simply products by companies.

Comment: If you're populating question and answers about your own product you should tred lightly and declare your interests. But otherwise I don't see how it matters

Comment: Is this post motivated by some actual questions, or is it purely hypothetical?

Comment: This is impossible/pointless to answer without seeing some examples. Can you show some?

Comment: This was intentionally kept abstract and question-agnostic.  It is only theoretical, but it comes to mind regularly when viewing questions about products that, so to speak, "no one has heard of."

Comment: [Link or it didn't happen](https://www.google.com/search?q=link+or+it+didn't+happen&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS501US501&oq=link+or+it+didn't+happen&aqs=chrome..69i57.3056j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#es_sm=122&espv=210&q=%22link+or+it+didn't+happen%22+stackoverflow+meta&safe=off)

Comment: @KirkWoll Although I'm all for not naming names and pointing fingers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Frankly any question and any tag is an advertisement for the product, regardless of the obscurity or popularity of the language.  In fact, Stack Overflow actually [sells "advertising"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30187/what-do-icons-on-the-tags-mean) on the tags by allowing companies to sponsor specific tags with logos.  So to answer your question, no, the obscurity of the language doesn't automatically make posts and tags into advertisements as they are advertisements already.

That leads to whether questions would be acceptable to the community.  You **cannot** use the tags to determine if a question is acceptable.  The existence of a tag or the lack of a tag does not determine whether questions are on-topic or off-topic.  Bad tags get created all the time and likewise, someone might not have thought to create a tag yet.  For example, [c#-6.0](/questions/tagged/c%23-6.0) doesn't exist yet, but when that language update is released, questions are certainly going to be on topic and someone will create the tag.  And there is a [jsfiddle](/questions/tagged/jsfiddle) tag, but that doesn't automatically make all jsfiddle questions on-topic.

To determine the on/off-topicness for a question, you need to go to the Help Center.  As long the question fits within the criteria specified by ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), then questions about any obscure language or API are certainly on topic.

But to consider whether they would be welcome, however, there are 2 other factors you need to consider.

1. Stack Overflow has a limit on [self promotion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57497/limits-for-self-promotion-in-answers) (note that I didn't say advertisement).  Answering a question by promoting a product that you are a stakeholder without disclosing your affiliation is greatly discouraged and often treated as Spam (and usually very aggressively).  Similarly, posting "answers" on any related question promoting the product, even when disclosing your affiliation, is also treated as Spam. This comes into play with self-answered questions.  You can't just come up with an on-topic question and then provide a self answer promoting the API.  (But just answering a question referencing a language/API you happen to be a fan of is not necessarily self promotion - you need to tread lightly though as fandom can be treated as self promotion, even if you aren't affiliated with the product when you start spaming multiple questions with the same recommendation of the language/API.
2. Questions need to have value for future visitors.  A question about an API so obscure, there is no documentation and only 2 people in the world are familiar with it is not going to have much future value.  Likewise, some API you created in your basement to access your personal media server is not going to be valuable to anyone other than you.  But an API that has a strong (but small) following and is easily available and accessible is certainly going to be on-topic.

Comment: The situation described in point #2 is exactly the sort I'm concerned about in terms of "crossing the line."  Does it not require a form of judgement based on how significant one feels the subject is?

Comment: @SouthpawHare like [@Pekka mentions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207280/does-obscurity-of-a-language-api-indicate-advertisement#comment659596_207280), without some more specific example, it is hard to provide any real advice and it will vary on a case-by-base basis (and a user-by-user basis).  It is one of the benefits (and problems) with community moderation.  Every user judges based on his/her own interpretation of the rules.