# I'd like vanity URLs

Tags: feature-request

Feature request: vanity URLs for users who hit some arbitrarily high rep score (like...1?)

For example, I'd like to be

```
https://stackoverflow.com/stevenalowe
```

or

```
https://stackoverflow.com/steven-a-lowe
```

instead of merely

https://stackoverflow.com/users/9345/steven-a-lowe

Comment: Yes, I realize this intersects with the unique-username issue.

Comment: ... and how would you solve it?

Comment: @Downvoter: the same way that careers does.

Comment: We already have Facebook...isn't that enough?

Comment: We [shouldn't put tags in titles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/171231).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

We already offer this on http://careers.stackoverflow.com -- and it's free, and can be linked to your so account.

Comment: I'd say this has better value for linking anyway. Your profile isn't nearly as useful to anyone you might link to than your CV.

Comment: +1; I don't use careers (still on track for the 50-years-of-service gold watch) and didn't know about that feature.

Comment: Now that Stack Overflow Jobs has been shut down, it might be nice to re-visit this.

Answer (score 6):

I love it.

Comment: You do realize you're stuck with that name for the next month, right?

Comment: We can call him the Great Question!

Comment: @mmyers I fully realized that. It's the cost of a nice punchline. Although `Questions/Ask` would have been even better. @ccornet I like that! :D

Comment: Ah you beat me to it :( Well I'm changing my name to `faq` !!!!!1111oneoneoneone

Comment: Dibs on 'reputation'

Comment: Dibs on `/questions/tagged/boat-programming`

Comment: What did you set your name to before you posted this?

Comment: @pop I think it was `questions`.

Answer (score 6):

I think that the current URL schema is fine. Permitting these "vanity urls" would be

- Difficult to standardize
- Permit conflicts between users
- What if you change your username?

Comment: I agree. Plus it would crowd the namespace on the topmost level. Nice idea essentially but more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: ... on second thought, I now already have my vanity page. Tee-hee!

Answer (score 1):

Well... SO certainly does place a certain value on a person's profile, as evidenced by the Blog Flair feature (which links to a profile on SOFU) and the fact that you can associate your profile with your careers.stackoverflow.com CV.

So the request for a vanity URL isn't necessarily an unfounded one, IMO.

That said... is it worth the effort to put it on SOFU? Not in my opinion. Especially given that careers.stackoverflow.com *does* offer a vanity URL.

So link to your CV on careers, rather than your SO profile, say I.

Answer (score 1):

I think that if it's something you have to earn the right to do (perhaps Page 1 users only, for example), it would be a great idea for the old Stack Overflow — perhaps even a way to help monetize the site, in that it's something you could charge extra for (on top of earning it).

But I don't think it fits the new Stack Exchange model as well, where a site can from anywhere.  The difference is the old Stack Overflow had a strong sense of helping you build your personal brand as a programmer, while Stack Exchange is more about communities and less personal.  All the UI elements of the old Stack Overflow are still there, but the system feels somehow less about the individual.