# What do you use your SOFU profile page for?

Tags: discussion, profile-page

I just came across the question [Feature request: vanity URLs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49462/feature-request-vanity-urls).  It's predicated on what is, to me at least, an interesting point.  **What do people use their SOFU profiles for?**

When I'm logged in, I'll use my profile's main page to easily jump to questions I've asked or answered, or occasionally the favorites tab like a bookmark.

And that's about it.  I don't use the other tabs — activity, accounts, reputation, prefs — pretty much at all.  Certainly I never give out the URL of my profile; it's not a secret, but who would want to visit my SO profile?  I'm curious what other people use their profiles for, and especially what's so important that they would want to have vanity ("facebook-style") URLs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use the Activity tab a lot because I comment on things that I need to follow up on later.

I mark things as favorite, but then I promptly forget why, so I don't use that tab as often as I'd like.

Comment: The favorites part is, sadly, a bit broken. It's just too basic to use in a meaningful way.

Comment: i use my MSO favorites page quite frequently -- i keep various FAQ links there for quick access when explaining why questions get closed on SU.  that way i don't have to search Meta for that link about the SU iphone policy...

Comment: @quack: That's a good idea.  I should clean mine out and put them to better use (both SO and MSO).

Comment: there's no hope for my SU faves... maybe i can nuke them from orbit...

Answer (score 1):

I use the activity tab because I can never remember if I just commented or answered something yesterday that I need to take a look at today. That's about it.

However, I think that question was more for the benefit of other people, not the owner of the profile.

Answer (score 0):

For absolutely nothing

(ever since my (casted) votes were not available anymore)

Answer (score 0):

I use my Meta profile in order to find the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/), because it's the fastest method for me (3 clicks) that doesn't involve changing my sort settings.

I use my SO profile in order to observe Views activity for my questions that are unanswered. That way I can tell if there is traffic or not, and subsequently if new comments may have been posted.