# Flair Linking to Careers.SO CV?

Tags: feature-request, jobs, flair

Ok, so [this request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49462/feature-request-vanity-urls) for vanity URLs and my own response about career.SO's offer of vanity URLs got me thinking...

What about offering standardized [flair](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flair) for our CVs on careers.SO? I don't mean the flair displayed on the CV to our SO accounts, I mean offering flair that links to our CV.

I know it's probably stupid, but I figure a link from a blog has more value to your CV than it does to your SO profile. Unless you prefer anonymity, of course.

So... I dunno. Just an idea? Thought I'd throw it out and see what everyone thought about it.

Comment: Come on... 7 up votes and not a single comment or reply? Let's discuss it, folks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wouldn't the flair simply be a plain ol' hyperlink to your public CV URL?

I really feel careers is different enough that it shouldn't be confusable with our existing site flairs.

Comment: I guess I didn't envision it as being identical to the existing flairs, just as something along the same lines.