# Excessive downvoting

Tags: support, down-votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Serial Downvoting Victim](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28756/serial-downvoting-victim)

I know, some of these answers are not my best ones but seriously, what is going on here:

[downvoting http://img59.imageshack.us/img59/2175/1006210002.png](http://img59.imageshack.us/img59/2175/1006210002.png)

That the downvotes are ~4 seconds apart makes it look like some automatic process.

I know that there are scripts that try to detect such patterns. And I don't care about the reputation ;)

---

But I don't think that someone did this... I think it is **something**!

Has anybody noticed something similar?

Comment: See e.g. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21575/mysterious-downvotes-14-random-downvotes-in-5-minutes

Comment: and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28756/serial-downvoting-victim

Comment: That's surprisingly fast for serial downvoting, since you can't downvote from the profile page like Reddit, you need to load each answer first

Comment: @Michael true, odd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a serial downvote, probably by one person you somehow pissed off.

Don't worry, the serial downvote detection mechanism will undo them within 24 hours or so.

Comment: Maybe I should stop trying to be funny ;)

Comment: Why did you change your name...? I looked at your profile and I still don't get it.

Comment: @George I changed my name in jest for the first time [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49462/feature-request-vanity-urls/49463#49463) and decided to join in on the fun of [changing your Meta name](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/26518#26518). The 30 day waiting period is the (relatively) newly imposed time span you have to wait before you can change your name again.

Comment: the irony is impossible to miss ;-)