# Sock Puppet Voting on SO?

Tags: support, sock-puppets

Take a look at [this user's reputation for March 24, 2011](https://stackoverflow.com/users/219166/erik-vold?tab=reputation).

He got 12 upvotes in one day, on 12 separate questions (Well above his daily average).  The entire collection of votes took only 9 minutes.

That's not even enough time to read and understand all the questions and answers.  And, the answers cover a variety of topics.

It sure seems like one single person decided to boost this user, irregardless of the quality of answers.

Is this legit?  A sock-puppet?

Comment: We'll find out after the voting-fraud script kicks in. (No idea when that will happen, but presumably within 24 hours of the votes.)

Comment: @Jon Seigel, thanks.  Do you have links about those scripts?  I'm still searching but have yet to find anything substantial.

Comment: Try http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/serial-downvotes and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/serial-upvotes as those are the most frequent contexts where voting fraud comes into play.

Comment: Thanks, I also just discovered ["Vote Fraud and You"](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/12/vote-fraud-and-you/) and ["More Voting Anomalies"](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/03/more-voting-anomalies/), both by Jeff Atwood.

Comment: It's been about a week and the improper votes are still there.   Per [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54486/serial-voter-algorithm-need-tweaking/54531#54531), I sent an email to the team about the gap in the improper voting detection.   I'll give it another week to see what results.

Comment: Why do you care how many points some other user has?

Comment: It looks to me like that's not enough votes to trigger the fraud scripts.

Comment: @Martin Doms, I care about gaming the system (stopping such).  Stackexchange is about finding the best answers.  This kind of voting works against that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This user appears to have a habit of answering his own questions, a fair proportion of those self-answers received upvotes.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5227701/wheres-the-documentation-for-nodejss-system-module/5227732#5227732)* is particularly bad: he has answered himself twice! [user108088](https://stackoverflow.com/users/108088/user108088) also appears a couple of times, but that could be coincidence.

*<sub>I'm following this up with a mod flag for merging & deletion of the two separate answers</sub>

Comment: I only see user108088 as the OP of one of the questions.

Comment: Yeah, and he's smart enough not to get carried away with sock-puppetry (if that's what's going on) nor to use the same IP.  This may be just a misguided fan, as Andrew Grimm guessed, but it still hurts the quest for best answers.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably not a sockpuppet, but some fan deciding to upvote several of his posts. That gets regarded as fraud anyway, so it'll get sorted out.

Comment: But then it's strange that there are _six_ upvoted self-answers, isn't it?

Comment: @Hendrik: It indicates serial upvoting, but it doesn't indicate that he's sock puppeting.

Comment: Well, it never got sorted out.  Lesson: Crime does pay in moderation?  Or misguided users subvert the system? (^_^)

Answer (score 1):

Vote history doesn't show any signs of collusion.  No user has received or given enough votes to smell strongly of socks...

Comment: What if they're pantyhose puppets?

Comment: @random: Nah, doesn't smell fishy at all.

Comment: eww. *shudder*

Comment: So, those 12 votes, on 12 topics, within 9 minutes, came from different user accounts?  (Even if true, that seems an amazing coincidence.)

Comment: @Brock: If indeed it came from different accounts, _then_ it would smell very strongly.