# Putting the "How to use this Tag" in the Tag Wiki Excerpt

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki, tag-autocomplete

Could we put in the Tag Wiki Excerpt a little description on how to use the tag? For example, [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) tags 90% of the time require a tag about the language you are using the Regex with. So we could write: "Regular expressions are a powerful form of declarative programming language, mainly used for pattern matching within strings. **When you use this tag, remember to add the tag of the language you are using the regular expression with**" or for "versioned" tags add a note that it's better to add the "main tag". So for example in the [c#-4.0](/questions/tagged/c%23-4.0) we could write "C# 4.0 introduces features like dynamic objects, and optional and named parameters.  There are also improvements in the area of COM interoperability. **It's often better to add the C# tag or the .NET tag to your questions when you use this tag**".

The reasoning: Regex questions DO need the language used, and newbies don't know it (and it's their right: nowhere it's written). Versioned tags suffer from the fact that many persons follow only the "main" tag and filter their question for that tag (so if you tag your question [c#-4.0](/questions/tagged/c%23-4.0) the possibilities you have a person will notice it are lower than if you had tagged it [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23)[c#-4.0](/questions/tagged/c%23-4.0). This happens especially if you misstag using tags like [asp.net](/questions/tagged/asp.net) or [silverlight](/questions/tagged/silverlight). Often your problem isn't really of asp.net or of silverlight. It's of pure C#.)

Comment: I regularly see tags with this, and I create tag wikis like this.  So in my opinion: Go ahead!

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96331/can-we-please-have-better-tag-wikis-and-excerpts

Comment: Ssee my improvement to the [tag:regex] tag.

Comment: @Robert Exactly as I was thinking! :-) Is it possible to use <br> to put it on a new line?

Answer (score 5):

I like your C# example, but advice on how to use tags should be more declarative:

> Use this tag if your question pertains specifically to C# 4.0 features.  Otherwise, use the C# tag.

This advice should go in the tag wiki excerpt, so that users can immediately see the advice in the dropdown and in the tag editor.  But *keep it very brief.*  The shorter the advice is, the more likely the advice will be read.