# What's the current policy on prefixing tags wiki excerpts with tag names?

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki-excerpt

I'm pretty sure I read somewhere that it is redundant to repeat the tag name in the first few words of the excerpt, but while searching for that, I came across another [question/answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96331/can-we-please-have-better-tag-wikis-and-excerpts) which seems to imply (or at least endorse) the opposite.

I've seen quite a lot of [suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/109788) recently which start: "[tagname] is used for...", where I'd have preferred just "used for...", as the excerpt is always (?) displayed in conjunction with the tag name.

Combine that with the answers here ([New tags page mangles tag wiki excerpts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82700/new-tags-page-mangles-tag-wiki-excerpts)) and I'm not quite sure *what* I'm supposed to do with these suggestions...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An excerpt is always shown in a place where it is understandable to which tag it is referring; the same is true for the tag wiki content.

The reason somebody starts the excerpt with the tag name is to write a sentence, instead of a phrase. To avoid using a phrase, it is sufficient to start the excerpt with "This tag," as done for the [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion).

[image: screenshot]

The con of using "This tag," "is," or "are" is that the excerpt is truncated when shown in the page listing all the tags.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: That excerpt still has a redundant clause using the tag name though -- "is a discussion which" is completely unnecessary. Editing now :)

Comment: My point is that if it is truncated, doesn't that indicate that it shouldn't be there in the first place, and shouldn't something in the guidelines on the edition page say so?

Comment: @agf That is the problem with the tags that use a common word as tag name. I am not sure it's redundant, in that case. Clearly, describing (for example) the "dog" tag as "topics related to dogs" doesn't help much.

Comment: @Benjol It is truncated on the page listing all the tags is because the software truncates the beginning of an excerpt in some cases. I am not sure it is truncated because that part should not be there; otherwise, it would be truncated in any places the excerpt is shown, which is not what happens. I think it's truncated to show what is more important in a place where the excerpt is truncated in any case (compare the second screenshot with the first one).