# Writing documentation about a topic in Stack Overflow

Tags: support, instant-self-answer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Posting and answering questions you have already found the answer to](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2706/posting-and-answering-questions-you-have-already-found-the-answer-to)

Sometimes I find **I know a good method to do something** (for example writing a clean and efficient function to convert rotations) or **I know a good explanation of a concept** that later could be useful for other users to understand how to program it, or how to study the concept (for example understanding quaternions).

If I think I know something that must be shared because it is going to be useful to many many people my quiestion is:

**Which is the right place to share it? How do I share it (as a question-answer, as a wiki,...)?**

Comment: You might find this of interest; [Posting and answering questions you have already found the answer to](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2706/posting-and-answering-questions-you-have-already-found-the-answer-to)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply, just post a question asking about it, and post an answer with what you think is a good solution. This is even encouraged, so don't worry and just go for it

Comment: Thats what I have been doing so far, but sometimes I think i would be nice to have some kind of wiki on the topic, a bit more extense.

Comment: Answer can be as long as you want (yes, there's some limit but I bet you won't exceed it). Anyone can edit an answer, so it is wiki by default

Answer (score 1):

If you want to share something general you might want to consider to contribute to the relevant tag wikis. Except for explaining the tag in question, linking to common question tag wikis are excellent places to define the concept of the tag's subject and to explain the concept. For example, you seem to have focused [opencv](/questions/tagged/opencv) questions and thus you might want to elaborate on common problems in that tag wiki https://stackoverflow.com/tags/opencv/info.

See also:

- [Tag Wiki best practices](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69584/tag-wiki-best-practices).
- [Who designs the best tag wiki?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1775/who-designs-the-best-tag-wiki) for links to good tag wikis on TeX.SX. It is not SO but might still give some inspiration for making good tag wikis.

Comment: Actually I created the one on quaternions, which was empty.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/quaternion

Comment: @Jav_Rock Then it might make sense for you to elaborate on that tag wiki if you want to share general knowledge.