# Recommended place to add names & versions?

Tags: discussion, questions

Usually I'll add any implementation specific info at the beginning or end of my question, such as: I'm using MySQL, Delphi 2007, PHP 5 etc.

This is often important or even critical info, though the tags also add this information.
Although I do add this in the question title, only when it's part of the question, not just tagged onto the end: "My query returns too many results PHP/MySQL".

What's the recommended place to include this info & should I be removing it from the question title in my suggested edits (only in the tagged-on-end style)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not really a need for such information in a title in my opinion. And certainly not of the form

> C++ - My Foos won't Bar
>   My Foos won't Bar - C++11

Sometimes I encounter titles where removing these "tags" (because essentially they are tags) would seriously screw up the title. If I can't think of a proper alternative, I sometimes rephrase it to:

> My Foos won't Bar in C++

But **only if** I can't think of a descriptive title without that information. If I can, I simply remove this question tagging from the title and make sure the question is tagged appropriately.

That's after all what the tags are meant to do. Tag with the appropriate tags. If it's related to a particular version only, then use that version-related tag. If it's a general question not limited to a particular version, use that one.

By all means feel free to also add such information into your question body though. There is no real harm in doing that if it helps you phrase your question. I personally try to stay away from bulleted lists of "tag info". But I don't really mind seeing them.

Comment: Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)"

Answer (score 3):

You can easily enter a block like so:

> #### My Setup:
>
> - PHP 5.4.x
> - MySQL 5.1.x
> - Windows Server 8
> - Etc, etc.

```
> ### My Setup:
> 
>  - PHP 5.4.x
>  - MySQL 5.1.x
>  - Windows Server 8
>  - Etc, etc.
```

At the beginning of the question. If the question is specifically related to a feature only [php5](/questions/tagged/php5) offers, use the appropriate tag for the question in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

Well if your question is dealing with a certain feature specific to a version of PHP/Delphi that you are using then you should use the correct tag for it.

- [php5](/questions/tagged/php5)
- [delphi-2007](/questions/tagged/delphi-2007)

If you are simply describing your setup, and for your specific problem you don't feel that it is necessarily version related, then you should use the normal non versioned tags, [php](/questions/tagged/php) [delphi](/questions/tagged/delphi), and simply mention the specific version at the start or end of your question.

With regard to removing this information from the title of a question, I think this would only be valid if the information already exists in the body of the post. If not, these specific 
(possibly vital) details should be edited into the post.