# Move the tags above main question area

Tags: feature-request, tags, questions

The auto-suggest feature is quite useful when asking questions but since including tags in the title [is discouraged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130208/135956) (unless they are intrinsic to the question), the auto suggest doesn't always have sufficient context to provide a good suggestion.

If the question is long, by the time you've entered tags, the suggestions are no longer visible. You (at least, I) don't always notice a good existing question which solves your problem. Quite often I'll be asking a question on (say) Python and see responses related to .Net. I habitually use multiple languages as do many of us (I have no idea if it uses my preferred tags/points too?)

I'd suggest that by moving the tags below the title, the auto suggest feature could infer more context and provide more relevant suggestions.

Comment: @random How is this a duplicate? The selected answer there is about surfacing tags in the title. It doesn't even _mention_ suggested answers. Same suggested solution but radically different problem.

Comment: Uhm. The closure was ... Over 6 years ago. I kinda doubt anyone would remember why after that long

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I'm sorry... For some reason, this popped up in my inbox as a notification