# What is the right way to phrase a question at SE: common language or technical language?

Tags: discussion, wording

Since a large part of the purpose of SE is to be the *source* of good Answers for seekers of knowledge, to *find* such Answers users need *first* to find the right Questions.

It therefor occurs to me that phrasing a Question using obscure or technical words (which an existing *Subject Matter Expert* would understand but which the *Average Joe* would not even recognize) is self-defeating since seekers would never find the Answered Question under the wording they are likely to search for it with.

As an example, a Question I recently asked used the term "**solar energy**" but another SE editor chose to rephrase the question using the term "**insolation**" instead. I do not dispute that this new word is far more precise than my original phrasing, but ***realistically*** how many users will come to SE and search for questions containing the word "insolation".

This post is not about my one *sol*itary example (pun intended) but rather about the larger question of SE's guidelines for how (or if?) to make the site more user friendly to seekers of knowledge. I believe the best approach would be to use more common language in Questions while still providing high quality Answers which use the more precise but less common language as needed.

Comments?

Comment: Why not edit the title to use both terms? "How much reduction of insolation (solar energy) would be required to stop global warming?"

Answer (score 5):

Stack Exchange sites should be written in a manner that is consistent with professional or technical writing within their own subject area.  This often involves things such as [removing 'thanks'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/213963) from the questions along with correcting capitalization, the use of punctuation, and other points.

Often, within a domain there is a technical jargon that may be difficult for a lay person to pick up without the proper experience.  However, there is already a system in place to work to make these questions more accessible - closing as a duplicate.

It is important for the first question to be findable by the experts - so that they may quickly close as a duplicate questions that are duplicates.  If the question is written without the specific technical jargon it can make it more difficult for the experts to find the question and result in multiple, duplicate questions with duplicate answers scattered about the site.

---

Changing "[Hypothetical: How much reduction of solar energy would be required to stop global warming?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/revisions/5286/1)" to "[How much reduction of insolation would be required to stop global warming?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/revisions/5286/2)" makes it easier for the experts to find for helping others find it (note that [this is the correct term](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insolation) for the concept).  For this specific question, you may also want to consider adding the tag [solar-terrestrial-physics](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solar-terrestrial-physics) to it to help others make it easier to find.  You may also wish to create and add the tag [albedo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albedo) - again making it easier for people familiar with the concept to find.  I will also point out that there may be some nuance to the jargon in the question (I didn't know that that was a term until I saw it referenced from albedo - which is something I *do* know of (thank you [Vangelis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albedo_0.39))).

Comment: Why not edit the title to use both terms? "How much reduction of insolation (solar energy) would be required to stop global warming?"

Comment: @DavidPostill thats akin to having a question that reads "How do I turn off my iPhone6 Plus (iOS phablet)?" which kind of reads silly.  The question body should be the place where the equivalence between the terms 'insolation' and 'solar energy' should be established - not the title.

Comment: If it improves searches (assuming google places more weight on the title rather than the body) then it is not silly. The people searching for the question are less likely to know the technical terms ...

Comment: Search results - both terms 1.3 M, solar energy 7.8 M, insolation 2.3 M (all with the rest of the title being the same)

Comment: And both ios and iphone are both tags on apple.stackexchange ... neither insolation or solar-anything are tags on earthscience.

Comment: @DavidPostill they are both ***tags*** and that is where the additional information should be (allowing for tag synonyms to handle duplication of terms).  That there are more documents out there that mention the lay person term than the technical term is not surprising, but should not be used as an indication that it is the term used by the experts on the site.  I will also point out that [tags are automatically added to titles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/) if the title text does not include the tag text.

Comment: Yes, I know about tags auto added to tiles - my last point was "insolation" and "solar-energy" are **not** tags - so they should be in the title.

Answer (score 1):

A question asker's objective is to get the question answered for them.  A question answerer's objective is to answer the question to the asker's specifications.  A later knowledge-seeker's objective is....???

Honestly, you can't predict ahead of time how someone in the future will want to come at a certain set of knowledge.  I have found many SE answers by very oblique searches.  Of course we should try to improve the quality of the knowledge for later searchers, but trying to phrase your question in such a way that makes that as easy as possible, well that seems like a sucker's game to me, because you just can't predict what the people of the future need to know, or what terms they'll use to think about those ideas.

So I think in general, question posters should post it in a way that's most comfortable to them, and that in their estimation, has the highest likelihood of attracting attention today.   By tag, this might mean sometimes you should use highly technical language suited to the question, and in other tag communities maybe you should do something else.  Hard to provide a general answer there.

Let the future users take care of themselves, because...well I'm not sure there's an alternative.

Comment: What then is the *correct* (*polite*? *politic*?) SE way to deal with edited question phrasing of **one's own Question** by another SE member? DO I simply change it back to whatever phrasing "*in [my] estimation, has the highest likelihood of attracting attention*" or would that be considered what the dreaded Wikipedia calls "edit warring"? Is there any written guidance on *that* subject?

Comment: @O.M.Y. Why not edit the title to use both terms? "How much reduction of insolation (solar energy) would be required to stop global warming?"