# Community Wiki card design looks weird/broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, community-wiki

Just noticed this weird design:

> [image]

Browsing other [random CW posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/179969/152859), noticed another version:

> [image]

Using the [wayback machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20150905231829/https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), found the good old design:

> [image]

Can this please be reverted back to the old look?

Chrome 47 under Windows 7 here, but most likely it's not browser dependant.

Comment: [Not just the CW card, either.](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/7389/pretty-boxes-not-rendering-correctly)

Comment: @AndrewLeach true, guess the major CSS changes they made affected the per-site designs as well.

Comment: I get really tired of the Live site being the beta test environment.

Comment: @Andrew I agree it's frustrating, but keep in mind that full team of testers cost a lot. Having those, SE would have to cut in other things, meaning less bug fixes, less requests fulfilled, less cookies for the developers...

Comment: It takes hardly any time at all to deliver `all.css` to a test environment (even on a laptop) and check it works. After all, it was developed somewhere, and it probably doesn't even work there.

Comment: @AndrewLeach oh, I'm sure they do it, and fix any major visible bugs before launching. Take a look [here](http://dev.stackoverflow.com). However, they can't possibly browse each of the 150 sites to look for such bugs, and small things like the recent wave of design bugs reported here are easily missed

Comment: @AndrewLeach We do test, we have a full dev environment. Occasionally we miss things. I know this looks like it should have been an easy catch, but when you think about it, almost anything seems like an easy catch once someone spots it :) We don't just ship and expect people to figure out what broke.

Comment: @Tim actually I don't think this one is easy to catch. The design bug mentioned by Andrew on http://english.stackexchange.com/ is way "bigger" and easy to spot, but probably affects only small number of sites, and like I said to Andrew, you can't really test each and every site of the 150 sites.

Comment: Well, perhaps my exasperation is fuelled by the environment I work in, where any change is rigorously tested. If it affects 150 sites, then 150 sites are tested, with a test script which is designed to test everything which should happen and everything we can think of which should not happen. Making a change to user cards should be easy to test and catch -- including this CW example. This isn't the first time and I'm afraid I don't buy it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue has been corrected. Problem, for those curious, related to a user card `width` being set to `auto` when there was no avatar. This was changed to `100%`.