# title of page of question asked

Tags: discussion, support

How is the title of page of a question asked is made? Eg, [javascript - What is the best way to detect a mobile device in jQuery? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3514784). The title of page starts with `javascript`. Does it mean that when asking a question, mandatory at least one tag is required which here is `javascript`. And therefore, in the list of tags on the question, `javascript` comes first. And therefore, title of page of this question starts with `javascript`.

Title of page here refers to `<title>` in the html code.

[image]

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<title>` is constructed of:

1. the "most popular" tag on the post (if not already in the title)

   - tags on the question are also sorted by popularity, descending
2. the question title
3. the name of the site

Since, of the three tags on that question, `javascript` is the most popular, you get:

`<title>javascript - What is the best way to detect a mobile device in jQuery? - Stack Overflow</title>`

Comment: some questions don't have `tags` in their titles