# Guidelines for duplicating tag text in a question title

Tags: discussion, tags, title, guidelines

Suppose we have a question like:

> How to check if an object is a string in JavaScript?

Obviously, we should tag the question with the `javascript` tag.

But do we need that 'in JavaScript' part in the question title then?

It looks redundant, since tags seem to be the best mean to put a context of the question. I believe short, concise and key-wordish titles are more preferrable, so I'd rather make the title like this and let tags say the rest:

> Check if object is string

Moreover, I noticed that often a question title in Google Search gets automatically prepended with the left-most SO tag text like this:

> javascript: How to check if an object is a string in JavaScript?

Which makes the 'in JavaScript' part even more questionable.

Could someone clarify this or point me to a question asking guidelines on this, if any?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it was already answered [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/254998) (thanks @Jenayah for pointing me to this), we absolutely do NOT need to add tags text to a question title.

So, the following titles should be avoided:

- [tag]: [question title]
- [question title] -- [tag] [tag] [tag]
- [question title] in [tag]
- [tag] [tag] [question title] [tag] [tag] [tag]
- [tag] [tag] [tag] [tag] [tag] [tag] [tag] [tag]