# Can you add tags in 'Similar questions' block for each displayed question?

Tags: feature-request, tags, similar-questions, visibility

I read that 'tags' on Stack Exchange are 'prohibited' in titles.

[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles)

So, to clearly identify a question, we need to read its title... and the tags.

Indeed, a question such as: *"How to compute length of string?"* is not clearly identified without its tags. (Example: [vb.net] or [java] or [javascript].)

Some months ago, a *Similar questions* block has been added when asking a question.

In this block it is possible to see similar questions based *only* on the title!

Since identification of questions is based on title *and* tags, the proposed similar questions based only on title are not always pertinent.

**Feature-request:**

Is it possible to add related tags just behind a question, so that when a user reads the title of a question, they know immediately the context of this question?

Currently, the user must click on the proposed question to know the context (tags) and it is *very* painful.

PS: If questions are identified (= primary key) by title and tags, each time a question is referenced, title and tags must be visible!