Should we repeat tags in question title?
In a comment to this question:
LilyPond - Put ALL noteheads to the left of stems, regardless of stem direction
a user asked OP to repeat the tag [lilypond] in the question title. This doesn't seem to follow the pattern of many other questions I see on SE. Is it really something we want the people who ask questions to do?

@DWW256 While adding proper tags is correct, also mentioning the software in the title (you don't need square brackets, just put it in the context of the phrase) or, at least, the question body is always better. […]


TL;DR: whoever asked the OP to repeat the tag is wrong.

The answer below (and in the duplicate) are good, but I really think you should ask about this on Music Meta.  I believe Music.SE is somewhat of an exception because most questions there aren’t related to programming, and so most users aren’t expecting to need to look for language tags.

@ElementsInSpace done: https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4041/should-we-repeat-tags-in-question-title I originally intended to post it on Music Meta. I posted by mistake here, probably while I was browsing other sites for existing answers.

That is probably going to be fairly subjective per-site and maybe even per-tag-family.
As an example, on Stack Overflow, and for tags in the SQL Server family, I edit "in SQL Server" out of titles, because - if the tag is present - that information is redundant, and just lengthens the title for no reason. But editors in other tag families may deem that type of information more useful than I do.
To get answers/consensus most appropriate for the music site, I'd suggest asking this question on that site's own meta. That said, the duplicate does show pretty strong consensus for the network in general.

Ah, I wanted to ask this on Music Meta actually. But I also now see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles?rq=1 which seems like a duplicate of my question, with the highest voted answer being "no", thus consistent with what you say. Thank you for the answer!

We used to do that on CR too. And then we ran into the issue that duplicates work quite differently on our site and while we don't encourage people to state tags in the title, sometimes adding a language is the easiest way of making the title coherent and unique at the same time.
