# Recognize URLs in angle brackets in comments

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, comments, hyperlinks

When I type a URL in angle brackets, such as <http://www.example.com&gt;, in a comment, the URL is not detected and linked.  Supporting this would allow links to be used more naturally in the flow of text in a comment.

This notation is recommended for embedding URLs in running text by [RFC 2396](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt); quotes are also recommended (I do not know if quotes work or not).

Comment: The fun part is that it works on posts. Gotta love consistency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked at this, but it'd be another regex pass on every single comment *as it is displayed*.

IMO the `<http://example.com>` syntax isn't useful enough to justify its presence in the comment subset -- just type the bare URL, or use the supported `[link](http://example.com)` syntax.

Answer (score 8):

You can just put the bare URL and it will be linked.  As an alternative to that, you can make a link say whatever you want (including the text of the URL) if you surround the text with `[]` followed by the URL in `()`.

```
[<http://www.example.com>](http://www.example.com)
```

See the working example below.

Comment: [<http://www.example.com>](http://www.example.com)

Comment: Thank you - this does work as a work-around.  I had not thought of it (I did not realize that the subset of Markdown supported in comments includes titled hyperlinks).

Answer (score 0):

Just add the raw url.  SO will automatically make it a live link.  See the comment for an example.

Comment: http://www.example.com

Comment: The above comment was created from the source markdown: `http://www.example.com`

Comment: Yes, adding raw links works.  However, it can be quite useful to use a delimiter, particularly if the URL is followed by text which is a valid URL character (such as a comma).